# What underlies this JavaScript idiom: var self = this?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I saw the following in the source for [WebKit HTML 5 SQL Storage Notes Demo](http://webkit.org/misc/DatabaseExample.html):

```
function Note() {
  var self = this;

  var note = document.createElement('div');
  note.className = 'note';
  note.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { return self.onMouseDown(e) }, false);
  note.addEventListener('click', function() { return self.onNoteClick() }, false);
  this.note = note;
  // ...
}
```

The author uses *self* in some places (the function body) and *this* in other places (the bodies of functions defined in the argument list of methods).  What's going on?  Now that I've noticed it once, will I start seeing it everywhere?

Comment: This is a JS language feature called “lexical closure."

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [var self = this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/337878/1497596).

Comment: the concept of THIS is explained explicitly here 
https://scotch.io/@alZami/understanding-this-in-javascript

Comment: Relevant example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/5610569 (to the question "How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?")

Answer (score 450, accepted):

See this [article on alistapart.com](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations). (Ed: The article has been updated since originally linked)

`self` is being used to maintain a reference to the original `this` even as the context is changing. It's a technique often used in event handlers (especially in closures).

**Edit:** Note that using `self` is now discouraged as [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) exists and has the potential to cause errors if you are not careful.

What you call the variable doesn't particularly matter. `var that = this;` is fine, but there's nothing magic about the name.

Functions declared inside a context (e.g. callbacks, closures) will have access to the variables/function declared in the same scope or above.

For example, a simple event callback:

```js
function MyConstructor(options) {
  let that = this;

  this.someprop = options.someprop || 'defaultprop';

  document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    alert(that.someprop);
  });
}

new MyConstructor({
  someprop: "Hello World"
});
```

Comment: Appears [that article](https://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations/#snippet26) morphed into using `var that = this;`

Comment: @BobStein Thanks. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 101):

I think the variable name 'self' should not be used this way anymore, since modern browsers provide a [global variable `self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) pointing to the global object of either a normal window or a WebWorker.

To avoid confusion and potential conflicts, you can write `var thiz = this` or `var that = this` instead.

Comment: I usually use `_this`

Comment: @djheru +1. so much nicer than "`that`" (which my brain will never get used to).

Comment: I started using "me" :)

Comment: Until modern browsers start providing a global variable _this, that, or me.

Comment: There's absolutely no problem with using the name `self` as long as you declare it as a `var`iable, it'll shadow the global. Of course if you forgot the `var` then it wouldn't work with any other name either.

Comment: @Bergi - One problem is that eslint won't catch it as an error if you forget to declare 'var self = this'.

Comment: @aaaaaa It does not? Have you declared `self` as an implicit global to eslint somewhere?

Comment: @Bergi Nope - it's implied via the browser environment: "env": { "browser": true }

Comment: @Matian2040 Existing codes which use `var self = this` continue to work, because the global `self` is shadowed, as @Bergi said. However If someone tries to modify existing code without carefully check existing uses of `self` in the same scope, he/she may unintentionally shadow the global `self` and breaks the code. That's why `var self = this` should be avoided.

Comment: @djheru I agree with the concept of _this to annotate top level this, and for me if the scope gets even deeper prepending additional "_" would work for me. `__this = this;` or it can be any prefix (except for $) :D

Comment: `they` is fashionably [singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). The animate variant of `this`.

Answer (score 38):

Yes, you'll see it everywhere. It's often `that = this;`.

See how `self` is used inside functions called by events? Those would have their own context, so `self` is used to hold the `this` that came into `Note()`.

The reason `self` is still available to the functions, even though they can only execute after the `Note()` function has finished executing, is that inner functions get the context of the outer function due to ***closure***.

Comment: For me the cogent point is that `self` has no special meaning. I personally prefer using a var named something other than `self` since it frequently confuses me, as I expect 'self' to be a reserved word.  So I like your answer. And in the example of the OP, I'd prefer `var thisNote = this` or similar.

Comment: @steve agreed, although I try to avoid using this/self references in general as they are very brittle in terms of maintainability.

Answer (score 28):

It should also be noted there is an alternative Proxy pattern for maintaining a reference to the original `this` in a callback if you dislike the `var self = this` idiom.

As a function can be called with a given context by using `function.apply` or `function.call`, you can write a wrapper that returns a function that calls your function with `apply` or `call` using the given context.  See jQuery's `proxy` function for an implementation of this pattern.  Here is an example of using it:

`var wrappedFunc = $.proxy(this.myFunc, this);`

`wrappedFunc` can then be called and will have your version of `this` as the context.

Answer (score 24):

As others have explained, `var self = this;` allows code in a [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to refer back to the parent scope.

However, it's now 2018 and ES6 is widely supported by all major web browsers. The `var self = this;` idiom isn't quite as essential as it once was.

It's now possible to avoid `var self = this;` through the use of [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

In instances where we would have used `var self = this`:

```
function test() {
    var self = this;
    this.hello = "world";
    document.getElementById("test_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(self.hello); // logs "world"
    });
};
```

We can now use an arrow function without `var self = this`:

```
function test() {
    this.hello = "world";
    document.getElementById("test_btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        console.log(this.hello); // logs "world"
    });
};
```

Arrow functions do not have their own `this` and simply assume the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 10):

It's a JavaScript quirk. When a function is a property of an object, more aptly called a method, **this** refers to the object. In the example of an event handler, the containing object is the element that triggered the event. When a standard function is invoked, **this** will refer to the global object. When you have nested functions as in your example, **this** does not relate to the context of the outer function at all. Inner functions do share scope with the containing function, so developers will use variations of `var that = this` in order to preserve the **this** they need in the inner function.

Answer (score 9):

The variable is captured by the inline functions defined in the method. `this` in the function will refer to another object. This way, you can make the function hold a reference to the `this` in the outer scope.

Answer (score 5):

Actually self is a reference to window (`window.self`) therefore when you say `var self = 'something'` you override a window reference to itself - because self exist in window object.

This is why most developers prefer `var that = this` over `var self = this;`

Anyway; `var that = this;` is not in line with the good practice ... presuming that your code will be revised / modified later by other developers you should use the most common programming standards in respect with developer community

Therefore you should use something like var `oldThis` / `var oThis` / etc - to be clear in your scope // ..is not that much but will save few seconds and few brain cycles

Comment: @prior I think it makes sense up until the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned several times above, 'self' is simply being used to keep a reference to 'this' prior to entering the funcition. Once in the function 'this' refers to something else.

Comment: @JohnPaul ... this _does_ provide an answer.  It might not be the right answer, but how can you say that "it is being used to ... " is not an answer to "why did he do this"?

Answer (score -4):

```
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;

  this.lastname = lastname;
  this.getfullname = function () {
    return `${this.firstname}   ${this.lastname}`;
  };

  let that = this;
  this.sayHi = function() {
    console.log(`i am this , ${this.firstname}`);
    console.log(`i am that , ${that.firstname}`);
  };
}

let thisss = new Person('thatbetty', 'thatzhao');

let thatt = {firstname: 'thisbetty', lastname: 'thiszhao'};
```

thisss.sayHi.call(thatt);

Comment: You should add some explanation with code that what you did special.

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here. You can see difference if you do var temp = thisss.sayHi and then call temp(). Now this.firstname will give undefined and that.firstname will give value because of closure created because of that variable.