# AngularJS : How to watch service variables?

Tags: angularjs, watch, angular-services

I have a service, say:

```
factory('aService', ['$rootScope', '$resource', function ($rootScope, $resource) {
  var service = {
    foo: []
  };

  return service;
}]);
```

And I would like to use `foo` to control a list that is rendered in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in foo">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

In order for the controller to detect when `aService.foo` is updated I have cobbled together this pattern where I add aService to the controller's `$scope` and then use `$scope.$watch()`:

```
function FooCtrl($scope, aService) {                                                                                                                              
  $scope.aService = aService;
  $scope.foo = aService.foo;

  $scope.$watch('aService.foo', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
    if(newVal) { 
      scope.foo = newVal;
    }
  });
}
```

This feels long-handed, and I've been repeating it in every controller that uses the service's variables.  Is there a better way to accomplish watching shared variables?

Comment: You can pass a third parameter to $watch set to true to deep watch aService and all its properties.

Comment: $scope.foo=  aService.foo is sufficient, you can lose the line above. And what it does inside $watch does not make sense, if you want to assign a new value to $scope.foo just do it...

Comment: Could you just reference `aService.foo` in the html markup? (like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/aNrw5Wo4Q0IxR2loipl5?p=preview)

Comment: I have added an example without Callbacks or $watches, see answer below (http://jsfiddle.net/zymotik/853wvv7s/)

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  And I also found that I could happily bind a control to "aService.foo"  (and then it'd be updated without any watches) but if my controller used "$scope.foo = aService.foo;" and I bound to "foo", then it'd never get updated.   Very strange.  Great question though.

Comment: @MikeGledhill, you're right. I think it's due to the nature of Javascript, you can see this pattern at many other places (not just in Angular, but in JS generally speaking). On one hand, you transfer the value (and it doesn't get bound) and on the other hand you transfer an object (or the value which references the object...), and that's why the properties are correctly updated (like perfectly shown in the example of Zymotik above).

Answer (score 280):

You can always use the good old observer pattern if you want to avoid the tyranny and overhead of `$watch`.

In the service:

```
factory('aService', function() {
  var observerCallbacks = [];

  //register an observer
  this.registerObserverCallback = function(callback){
    observerCallbacks.push(callback);
  };

  //call this when you know 'foo' has been changed
  var notifyObservers = function(){
    angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function(callback){
      callback();
    });
  };

  //example of when you may want to notify observers
  this.foo = someNgResource.query().$then(function(){
    notifyObservers();
  });
});
```

And in the controller:

```
function FooCtrl($scope, aService){
  var updateFoo = function(){
    $scope.foo = aService.foo;
  };

  aService.registerObserverCallback(updateFoo);
  //service now in control of updating foo
};
```

Comment: How would you remove the registered callback after the user leaves the page with the FooCtrl?

Comment: @Moo listen for the `$destory` event on the scope and add an unregister method to `aService`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you should $scope.$apply the change in the observer callback in the controller. At least I had to, because all the changes to my service come through events from a flash.

Comment: What are pros of this solution? It needs more code in a service, and somewhat the same amount of code in a controller (since we also need to unregister on $destroy). I could say for execution speed, but in most cases it just won't matter.

Comment: not sure how this is a better solution than $watch, the questioner was asking for a simple way of sharing the data, it looks even more cumbersome. I would rather use $broadcast than this

Comment: `$watch` vs observer pattern is simply choosing whether to poll or to push, and is basically a matter of performance, so use it when performance matters. I use observer pattern when otherwise I would have to "deep" watch complex objects. I attach whole services to the $scope instead of watching single service values. I avoid angular's $watch like the devil, there is enough of that happening in directives and in native angular data-binding.

Comment: I would suggest this solution even when performance is not so much an issue because the behavior is explicitly defined in the code and doesn't depend on library magic. Good answer!

Comment: The reason why we're using a framework like Angular is to not cook up our own observer patterns.

Comment: I don't find this too amazing -- apologies if I seem crude -- but this is a simple `getSet` approach. Either use an `Object.defineProperties(object, ...)` or if you're looking for a `pubSub` methodology, you may as well use `$rootScope.$on('changed:someData', setSomeData)` & `$rootScope.$broadcast('changed:someData', someData)`. IMAGINARY POINTS OFF for this answer :(

Comment: You need to have a very good use case to justify reimplementing events in Angular.

Comment: Aren't we missing 'return this;' at the end of service definition?

Comment: Not very Angular, compared to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20863597/418150

Comment: @CodeWhisperer why would we use angulars $broadcast here? Why would I broadcast an event which is probably meant for just a single controller rather than the whole app? And why shouldn't we use a well known pattern if it would fit in the case?

Comment: $watch and $rootScope.$emit are both quite expensive as they have to traverse the whole scope, right? 
As I am working a lot with really cpu expensive frontend, this matters to me and I also already used it in 1.4. Observer pattern still is a direct connection and nothing has to be traversed, which for high n it might be faster. Especially if there already a lot of rootScope listeners?

I didnt benchmark but thats how i understand it. if you have other information, please enlighten me!

Comment: @CodeWhisperer 's upvoted response shouldn't be so upvoted. While true, it completely ignores the rationale of creating your own observer pattern in a service, i.e. performance. If you've ever used watchers in an angularjs application you know how quickly they can degrade performance. A lighter weight approach like this surely has some applicability.

Comment: consider $watch works with the methodology of long polling where as observer pattern calls method(s) only once (with right garbage collecting implementation) when job is done. I think observer pattern leads far beyond in performance-wise in my opinion.

Answer (score 232):

In a scenario like this, where multiple/unkown objects might be interested in changes, use `$rootScope.$broadcast` from the item being changed.

Rather than creating your own registry of listeners (which have to be cleaned up on various $destroys), you should be able to `$broadcast` from the service in question.

You must still code the `$on` handlers in each listener but the pattern is decoupled from multiple calls to `$digest` and thus avoids the risk of long-running watchers.

This way, also, listeners can come and go from the *DOM* and/or different child scopes without the service changing its behavior.

** update: examples **

Broadcasts would make the most sense in "global" services that could impact countless other things in your app.  A good example is a User service where there are a number of events that could take place such as login, logout, update, idle, etc.  I believe this is where broadcasts make the most sense because any scope can listen for an event, without even injecting the service, and it doesn't need to evaluate any expressions or cache results to inspect for changes.  It just fires and forgets (so make sure it's a fire-and-forget notification, not something that requires action)

```
.factory('UserService', [ '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
   var service = <whatever you do for the object>

   service.save = function(data) {
     .. validate data and update model ..
     // notify listeners and provide the data that changed [optional]
     $rootScope.$broadcast('user:updated',data);
   }

   // alternatively, create a callback function and $broadcast from there if making an ajax call

   return service;
}]);
```

The service above would broadcast a message to every scope when the save() function completed and the data was valid.  Alternatively, if it's a $resource or an ajax submission, move the broadcast call into the callback so it fires when the server has responded.  Broadcasts suit that pattern particularly well because every listener just waits for the event without the need to inspect the scope on every single $digest. The listener would look like:

```
.controller('UserCtrl', [ 'UserService', '$scope', function(UserService, $scope) {

  var user = UserService.getUser();

  // if you don't want to expose the actual object in your scope you could expose just the values, or derive a value for your purposes
   $scope.name = user.firstname + ' ' +user.lastname;

   $scope.$on('user:updated', function(event,data) {
     // you could inspect the data to see if what you care about changed, or just update your own scope
     $scope.name = user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname;
   });

   // different event names let you group your code and logic by what happened
   $scope.$on('user:logout', function(event,data) {
     .. do something differently entirely ..
   });

 }]);
```

One of the benefits of this is the elimination of multiple watches. If you were combining fields or deriving values like the example above, you'd have to watch both the firstname and lastname properties. Watching the getUser() function would only work if the user object was replaced on updates, it would not fire if the user object merely had its properties updated.  In which case you'd have to do a deep watch and that is more intensive.

$broadcast sends the message from the scope it's called on down into any child scopes.  So calling it from $rootScope will fire on every scope.  If you were to $broadcast from your controller's scope, for example, it would fire only in the scopes that inherit from your controller scope.  $emit goes the opposite direction and behaves similarly to a DOM event in that it bubbles up the scope chain.

Keep in mind that there are scenarios where $broadcast makes a lot of sense, and there are scenarios where $watch is a better option - especially if in an isolate scope with a very specific watch expression.

Comment: Getting out of the $digest cycle is a Good Thing, especially if the changes you're watching aren't a value that will directly and immediately go into the DOM.

Comment: Is there away to avoid .save() method.  Seems like overkill when you are just monitoring the update of a single variable in the sharedService.  Can we watch the variable from within the sharedService and broadcast when it changes?

Comment: I tried quite a few ways to share data between controllers, but this is the only one that worked. Well played, sir.

Comment: I prefer this to the other answers, seems less *hacky*, thanks

Comment: This is the correct design pattern only if your consuming controller has multiple possible sources of the data; in other words, if you have a MIMO situation (Multiple Input/Multiple Output). If you're just using a one-to-many pattern, you should be using direct object referencing and letting the Angular framework do the two-way binding for you. Horkyze linked this below, and it's a good explanation of the automatic two-way binding, and it's limitations: http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/

Answer (score 49):

I'm using similar approach as @dtheodot but using angular promise instead of passing callbacks

```
app.service('myService', function($q) {
    var self = this,
        defer = $q.defer();

    this.foo = 0;

    this.observeFoo = function() {
        return defer.promise;
    }

    this.setFoo = function(foo) {
        self.foo = foo;
        defer.notify(self.foo);
    }
})
```

Then wherever just use `myService.setFoo(foo)` method to update `foo` on service. In your controller you can use it as:

```
myService.observeFoo().then(null, null, function(foo){
    $scope.foo = foo;
})
```

First two arguments of `then` are success and error callbacks, third one is notify callback.

[Reference for $q.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: What would be the advantage of this method over the $broadcast described bellow by Matt Pileggi?

Comment: Well both methods have their uses. Advantages of broadcast for me would be human readability and possibility to listen on more places to the same event. I guess the main disadvantage is that broadcast is emiting message to all descendant scopes so it may be a performance issue.

Comment: I was having a problem where doing `$scope.$watch` on a service variable wasn't seeming to work (the scope I was watching on was a modal that inherited from `$rootScope`) - this worked. Cool trick, thanks for sharing!

Comment: How would you clean up after yourself with this approach? Is it possible to remove the registered callback from the promise when the scope is destroyed?

Comment: Good question. I honestly don't know. I'll try to do some tests on how could you remove notify callback from promise.

Answer (score 43):

Without watches or observer callbacks (http://jsfiddle.net/zymotik/853wvv7s/):

JavaScript:

```
angular.module("Demo", [])
    .factory("DemoService", function($timeout) {

        function DemoService() {
            var self = this;
            self.name = "Demo Service";

            self.count = 0;

            self.counter = function(){
                self.count++;
                $timeout(self.counter, 1000);
            }

            self.addOneHundred = function(){
                self.count+=100;
            }

            self.counter();
        }

        return new DemoService();

    })
    .controller("DemoController", function($scope, DemoService) {

        $scope.service = DemoService;

        $scope.minusOneHundred = function() {
            DemoService.count -= 100;
        }

    });
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div>
        <h4>{{service.name}}</h4>
        <p>Count: {{service.count}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This JavaScript works as we are passing an object back from the service rather than a value. When a JavaScript object is returned from a service, Angular adds watches to all of its properties.

Also note that I am using 'var self = this' as I need to keep a reference to the original object when the $timeout executes, otherwise 'this' will refer to the window object.

Comment: This is a great approach! Is there a way to bind just a property of a service to the scope instead of the entire service? Just doing `$scope.count = service.count` doesn't work.

Comment: You could also nest the property inside of an (arbitrary) object so that it's passed by reference. `$scope.data = service.data` `<p>Count: {{ data.count }}</p>`

Comment: Excellent approach! While there are a lot of strong, functional answers on this page, this is by far a) the easiest to implement, and b) the easiest to understand when reading over the code. This answer should be a lot higher than it currently is.

Comment: Thanks @CodeMoose, I've simplified it even further today for those new to AngularJS/JavaScript.

Comment: could you please tell me what is the advantage of having the line   `var self = this;` ? why not just use `this`

Comment: Hi @Afflatus, self is being used to maintain a reference to the original this. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this

Comment: In my opinion you are confusing people with `self` right here. There is no point using them for creating function because `this` and `self` are referring to the same object. It makes sense to use `self` only inside the function and then again it is not necessary to use it because you can use `.bind(this)`  and when you have a case when you can't use `.bind()` only then you would use `self`.

Comment: Thank-you for your comments @Stamy. Please can you demonstrate a simpler approach in a jsFiddle? We can then compare and update the example if needed. We do require a reference to the original `this` when using the `$timeout` function.

Comment: Here is a link with a code: https://jsbin.com/guwogo/edit?js,console . I added two approaches, I am fine with either approach. But I would never use `self` for creating everything. It might be good if you don't understand how `this` and scopes works but I have never seen anything like this in any decent library.

Comment: @Zymotik , So, you would still need $watch or $broadcast ,though, when displaying the service data on more than one controller at the same time? http://jsfiddle.net/qqejytbz/1/

Comment: @NoobSter no, you would not

Comment: @Zymotik , Thanks for the reply. I know this is old. In my fiddle posted above, (forked from your example) the count is not able to update in both controllers, unless I use a $watch. What is the correct way to do this? Fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/qqejytbz/1

Comment: i moved this to it's own question if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786796/how-to-keep-service-data-the-same-on-multiple-controllers-without-using-watch

Comment: @noobster please see the first two comments, as I believe this answers your question.

Comment: May God bless you. I have wasted like million hours I would say. Because I was struggling with 1.5 and angularjs shifting from 1 to 2 and also wanted to share data

Answer (score 29):

I stumbled upon this question looking for something similar, but I think it deserves a thorough explanation of what's going on, as well as some additional solutions.

When an angular expression such as the one you used is present in the HTML, Angular automatically sets up a `$watch` for `$scope.foo`, and will update the HTML whenever `$scope.foo` changes.

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in foo">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

The unsaid issue here is that one of two things are affecting `aService.foo`  such that the changes are undetected. These two possibilities are:

1. `aService.foo` is getting set to a new array each time, causing the reference to it to be outdated.
2. `aService.foo` is being updated in such a way that a `$digest` cycle is not triggered on the update.

---

## Problem 1: Outdated References

Considering the first possibility, assuming a `$digest` is being applied, if `aService.foo` was always the same array, the automatically set `$watch` would detect the changes, as shown in the code snippet below.

## Solution 1-a: Make sure the array or object is the *same object* on each update

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('aService', [
    '$interval',
    function($interval) {
      var service = {
        foo: []
      };

      // Create a new array on each update, appending the previous items and 
      // adding one new item each time
      $interval(function() {
        if (service.foo.length < 10) {
          var newArray = []
          Array.prototype.push.apply(newArray, service.foo);
          newArray.push(Math.random());
          service.foo = newArray;
        }
      }, 1000);

      return service;
    }
  ])
  .factory('aService2', [
    '$interval',
    function($interval) {
      var service = {
        foo: []
      };

      // Keep the same array, just add new items on each update
      $interval(function() {
        if (service.foo.length < 10) {
          service.foo.push(Math.random());
        }
      }, 1000);

      return service;
    }
  ])
  .controller('FooCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'aService',
    'aService2',
    function FooCtrl($scope, aService, aService2) {
      $scope.foo = aService.foo;
      $scope.foo2 = aService2.foo;
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <h1>Array changes on each update</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in foo">{{ item }}</div>
    <h1>Array is the same on each udpate</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in foo2">{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the ng-repeat supposedly attached to `aService.foo` does not update when `aService.foo` changes, but the ng-repeat attached to `aService2.foo` *does*. This is because our reference to `aService.foo` is outdated, but our reference to `aService2.foo` is not. We created a reference to the initial array with `$scope.foo = aService.foo;`, which was then discarded by the service on it's next update, meaning `$scope.foo` no longer referenced the array we wanted anymore.

However, while there are several ways to make sure the initial reference is kept in tact, sometimes it may be necessary to change the object or array. Or what if the service property references a primitive like a `String` or `Number`? In those cases, we cannot simply rely on a reference. So what *can* we do?

Several of the answers given previously already give some solutions to that problem. However, I am personally in favor of using the simple method suggested by [Jin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables/33644472#comment33451712_12576798) and [thetallweeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables/33644472#comment40958475_12576798) in the comments:

> just reference aService.foo in the html markup

## Solution 1-b: Attach the service to the scope, and reference `{service}.{property}` in the HTML.

Meaning, just do this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in aService.foo">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function FooCtrl($scope, aService) {
    $scope.aService = aService;
}
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('aService', [
    '$interval',
    function($interval) {
      var service = {
        foo: []
      };

      // Create a new array on each update, appending the previous items and 
      // adding one new item each time
      $interval(function() {
        if (service.foo.length < 10) {
          var newArray = []
          Array.prototype.push.apply(newArray, service.foo);
          newArray.push(Math.random());
          service.foo = newArray;
        }
      }, 1000);

      return service;
    }
  ])
  .controller('FooCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'aService',
    function FooCtrl($scope, aService) {
      $scope.aService = aService;
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <h1>Array changes on each update</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in aService.foo">{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

That way, the `$watch` will resolve `aService.foo` on each `$digest`, which will get the correctly updated value.

This is kind of what you were trying to do with your workaround, but in a much less round about way. You added an unnecessary `$watch` in the controller which explicitly puts `foo` on the `$scope` whenever it changes. You don't need that extra `$watch` when you attach `aService` instead of `aService.foo` to the `$scope`, and bind explicitly to `aService.foo` in the markup.

---

Now that's all well and good assuming a `$digest` cycle is being applied. In my examples above, I used Angular's [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service to update the arrays, which automatically kicks off a `$digest` loop after each update. But what if the service variables (for whatever reason) aren't getting updated inside the "Angular world". In other words, we *dont* have a `$digest` cycle being activated automatically whenever the service property changes?

---

## Problem 2: Missing [`$digest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest)

Many of the solutions here will solve this issue, but I agree with [Code Whisperer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables/33644472#comment38413763_17558885):

> The reason why we're using a framework like Angular is to not cook up our own observer patterns

Therefore, I would prefer to continue to use the `aService.foo` reference in the HTML markup as shown in the second example above, and not have to register an additional callback within the Controller.

## Solution 2: Use a setter and getter with `$rootScope.$apply()`

I was surprised no one has yet suggested the use of a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). This capability was introduced in ECMAScript5, and has thus been around for years now. Of course, that means if, for whatever reason, you need to support really old browsers, then this method will not work, but I feel like getters and setters are vastly underused in JavaScript. In this particular case, they could be quite useful:

```
factory('aService', [
  '$rootScope',
  function($rootScope) {
    var realFoo = [];

    var service = {
      set foo(a) {
        realFoo = a;
        $rootScope.$apply();
      },
      get foo() {
        return realFoo;
      }
    };
  // ...
}
```

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('aService', [
    '$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {
      var realFoo = [];

      var service = {
        set foo(a) {
          realFoo = a;
          $rootScope.$apply();
        },
        get foo() {
          return realFoo;
        }
      };

      // Create a new array on each update, appending the previous items and 
      // adding one new item each time
      setInterval(function() {
        if (service.foo.length < 10) {
          var newArray = [];
          Array.prototype.push.apply(newArray, service.foo);
          newArray.push(Math.random());
          service.foo = newArray;
        }
      }, 1000);

      return service;
    }
  ])
  .controller('FooCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'aService',
    function FooCtrl($scope, aService) {
      $scope.aService = aService;
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <h1>Using a Getter/Setter</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in aService.foo">{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here I added a 'private' variable in the service function: `realFoo`. This get's updated and retrieved using the `get foo()` and `set foo()` functions respectively on the `service` object.

Note the use of `$rootScope.$apply()` in the set function. This ensures that Angular will be aware of any changes to `service.foo`. If you get 'inprog' errors see [this useful reference page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog), or if you use Angular >= 1.3 you can just use `$rootScope.$applyAsync()`.

Also be wary of this if `aService.foo` is being updated very frequently, since that could significantly impact performance. If performance would be an issue, you could set up an observer pattern similar to the other answers here using the setter.

Comment: This is the correct, and easiest solution.  As @NanoWizard say, $digest watches for `services` not for properties that belong to the service itself.

Answer (score 28):

As far as I can tell, you dont have to do something as elaborate as that. You have already assigned foo from the service to your scope and since foo is an array ( and in turn an object it is assigned by reference! ). So, all that you need to do is something like this :

```
function FooCtrl($scope, aService) {                                                                                                                              
  $scope.foo = aService.foo;

 }
```

If some, other variable in this same Ctrl is dependant on foo changing then yes, you would need a watch to observe foo and make changes to that variable. But as long as it is a simple reference watching is unnecessary. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If the variable in the service is a "primitive" instead of an object, like a string, would that, in turn, require a ```$watch```?

Comment: I tried, and I couldn't get `$watch` to work with a primitive.  Instead, I defined a method on the service that would return the primitive value: `somePrimitive() = function() { return somePrimitive }` And I assigned a $scope property to that method:  `$scope.somePrimitive = aService.somePrimitive;`. Then I used the scope method in the HTML:  `<span>{{somePrimitive()}}</span>`

Comment: @MarkRajcok No don't use primitives. Add them in a object. Primitives are not mutables and so 2way data binding will not work

Comment: @JimmyKane, yes, primitives should not be used for 2-way databinding, but I think the question was about watching service variables, not setting up 2-way binding.  If you only need to watch a service property/variable, an object is not required -- a primitive can be used.

Comment: In this set up I am able to change aService values from the scope. But the scope does not change in response the aService changing.

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. Simply assigning `$scope.foo = aService.foo` does not update the scope variable automatically.

Comment: Correct you cannot assign a scope variable from a Service variable and then $watch('foo' ,...   I am using angular 1.3 to test and the watch does not get fired when the service variable changes

Comment: I tried few times before ... I knew there was a better than using scope but i did not succeed when i tried it. This evening i finally did it, so awesome :) !!!
You sir deserves more upvotes !

Comment: @lostintranslation what was your solution for 1.3?

Comment: I can't understand the upvotes since this doesn't work. Even if in the service I have an object, its value is not automatically updated in the controller.

Comment: All this from a "framework" that was supposed to make our lives easier! No wonder they started again! LOL.

Answer (score 9):

You can insert the service in $rootScope and watch:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, aService){
    $rootScope.aService = aService;
    $rootScope.$watch('aService', function(){
        alert('Watch');
    }, true);
});
```

In your controller:

```
myApp.controller('main', function($scope){
    $scope.aService.foo = 'change';
});
```

Other option is to use a external library like: https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS

Works with: IE 9+, FF 4+, SF 5+, WebKit, CH 7+, OP 12+, BESEN, Node.JS , Rhino 1.7+

You can observe the changes of one, many or all object attributes.

Example:

```
var ex3 = {
    attr1: 0,
    attr2: "initial value of attr2",
    attr3: ["a", 3, null]
};   
watch(ex3, function(){
    alert("some attribute of ex3 changes!");
});
ex3.attr3.push("new value");​
```

Comment: I CAN'T BELIEVE THIS ANSWER IS NOT THE TOP-MOST-VOTED!!! This is the most elegant solution (IMO) as it reduces informational-entropy & probably mitigates the need for additional Mediation handlers. I would vote this up more if I could...

Comment: Adding all your services to the $rootScope, its benefits and it's potential pitfalls, are detailed somewhat here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573023/is-binding-objects-to-angulars-rootscope-in-a-service-bad

Answer (score 6):

You can watch the changes within the factory itself and then broadcast a change

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory('aFactory', function ($rootScope) {
    // Define your factory content
    var result = {
        'key': value
    };

    // add a listener on a key        
    $rootScope.$watch(function () {
        return result.key;
    }, function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
        // This is called after the key "key" has changed, a good idea is to broadcast a message that key has changed
        $rootScope.$broadcast('aFactory:keyChanged', newValue);
    }, true);

    return result;
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('aController', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('aFactory:keyChanged', function currentCityChanged(event, value) {
        // do something
    });
}]);
```

In this manner you put all the related factory code within its description then you can only rely on the broadcast from outside

Answer (score 6):

**==UPDATED==**

Very simple now in $watch.

[Pen here](http://codepen.io/hayatbiralem/pen/LpQQrw).

HTML:

```
<div class="container" data-ng-app="app">

  <div class="well" data-ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <p><strong>FooController</strong></p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><a href="" ng-click="setItems([ { name: 'I am single item' } ])">Send one item</a></p>
        <p><a href="" ng-click="setItems([ { name: 'Item 1 of 2' }, { name: 'Item 2 of 2' } ])">Send two items</a></p>
        <p><a href="" ng-click="setItems([ { name: 'Item 1 of 3' }, { name: 'Item 2 of 3' }, { name: 'Item 3 of 3' } ])">Send three items</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p><a href="" ng-click="setName('Sheldon')">Send name: Sheldon</a></p>
        <p><a href="" ng-click="setName('Leonard')">Send name: Leonard</a></p>
        <p><a href="" ng-click="setName('Penny')">Send name: Penny</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well" data-ng-controller="BarCtrl">
    <p><strong>BarController</strong></p>
    <p ng-if="name">Name is: {{ name }}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('PostmanService', function() {
  var Postman = {};
  Postman.set = function(key, val) {
    Postman[key] = val;
  };
  Postman.get = function(key) {
    return Postman[key];
  };
  Postman.watch = function($scope, key, onChange) {
    return $scope.$watch(
      // This function returns the value being watched. It is called for each turn of the $digest loop
      function() {
        return Postman.get(key);
      },
      // This is the change listener, called when the value returned from the above function changes
      function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          // Only update if the value changed
          $scope[key] = newValue;
          // Run onChange if it is function
          if (angular.isFunction(onChange)) {
            onChange(newValue, oldValue);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  };
  return Postman;
});

app.controller('FooCtrl', ['$scope', 'PostmanService', function($scope, PostmanService) {
  $scope.setItems = function(items) {
    PostmanService.set('items', items);
  };
  $scope.setName = function(name) {
    PostmanService.set('name', name);
  };
}]);

app.controller('BarCtrl', ['$scope', 'PostmanService', function($scope, PostmanService) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.name = '';
  PostmanService.watch($scope, 'items');
  PostmanService.watch($scope, 'name', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    alert('Hi, ' + newVal + '!');
  });
}]);
```

Comment: i like the PostmanService but how i must change $watch function on controller if i need to listen more than one variable?

Comment: Hi jedi, thanks for the heads up! I updated the pen and the answer. I recomment to add another watch function for that. So, I added a new feature to PostmanService. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Actually, yes it is :) If you share more detail of the problem maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Building on **dtheodor's** answer you could use something similar to the below to ensure that you don't forget to unregister the callback... Some may object to passing the `$scope` to a service though.

```
factory('aService', function() {
  var observerCallbacks = [];

  /**
   * Registers a function that will be called when
   * any modifications are made.
   *
   * For convenience the callback is called immediately after registering
   * which can be prevented with `preventImmediate` param.
   *
   * Will also automatically unregister the callback upon scope destory.
   */
  this.registerObserver = function($scope, cb, preventImmediate){
    observerCallbacks.push(cb);

    if (preventImmediate !== true) {
      cb();
    }

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
      observerCallbacks.remove(cb);
    });
  };

  function notifyObservers() {
    observerCallbacks.forEach(function (cb) {
      cb();
    });
  };

  this.foo = someNgResource.query().$then(function(){
    notifyObservers();
  });
});
```

Array.remove is an extension method which looks like this:

```
/**
 * Removes the given item the current array.
 *
 * @param  {Object}  item   The item to remove.
 * @return {Boolean}        True if the item is removed.
 */
Array.prototype.remove = function (item /*, thisp */) {
    var idx = this.indexOf(item);

    if (idx > -1) {
        this.splice(idx, 1);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my generic approach.

```
mainApp.service('aService',[function(){
        var self = this;
        var callbacks = {};

        this.foo = '';

        this.watch = function(variable, callback) {
            if (typeof(self[variable]) !== 'undefined') {
                if (!callbacks[variable]) {
                    callbacks[variable] = [];
                }
                callbacks[variable].push(callback);
            }
        }

        this.notifyWatchersOn = function(variable) {
            if (!self[variable]) return;
            if (!callbacks[variable]) return;

            angular.forEach(callbacks[variable], function(callback, key){
                callback(self[variable]);
            });
        }

        this.changeFoo = function(newValue) {
            self.foo = newValue;
            self.notifyWatchersOn('foo');
        }

    }]);
```

In Your Controller

```
function FooCtrl($scope, aService) {
    $scope.foo;

    $scope._initWatchers = function() {
        aService.watch('foo', $scope._onFooChange);
    }

    $scope._onFooChange = function(newValue) {
        $scope.foo = newValue;
    }

    $scope._initWatchers();

}

FooCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'aService'];
```

Answer (score 2):

For those like me just looking for a simple solution, this does almost exactly what you expect from using normal $watch in controllers.
The only difference is, that it evaluates the string in it's javascript context and not on a specific scope. You'll have to inject $rootScope into your service, although it is only used to hook into the digest cycles properly.

```
function watch(target, callback, deep) {
    $rootScope.$watch(function () {return eval(target);}, callback, deep);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

while facing a very similar issue I watched a function in scope and had the function return the service variable. I have created a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/tLp2b47n/5/). you can find the code below.

```
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.factory("randomService", function($timeout){
    var retValue = {};
    var data = 0;

    retValue.startService = function(){
        updateData();
    }

    retValue.getData = function(){
        return data;
    }

    function updateData(){
        $timeout(function(){
            data = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            updateData()
        }, 500);
    }

    return retValue;
});

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, randomService){
    $scope.data = 0;
    $scope.dataUpdated = 0;
    $scope.watchCalled = 0;
    randomService.startService();

    $scope.getRandomData = function(){
        return randomService.getData();    
    }

    $scope.$watch("getRandomData()", function(newValue, oldValue){
        if(oldValue != newValue){
            $scope.data = newValue;
            $scope.dataUpdated++;
        }
            $scope.watchCalled++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question but it turned out my problem was that I was using setInterval when I should have been using the angular $interval provider.  This is also the case for setTimeout (use $timeout instead).  I know it's not the answer to the OP's question, but it might help some, as it helped me.

Comment: You can use `setTimeout`, or any other non-Angular function, but just don't forget to wrap the code in the callback with `$scope.$apply()`.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a really great solution on the other thread with a similar problem but totally different approach. Source: [AngularJS : $watch within directive is not working when $rootScope value is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265695/watch-within-directive-is-not-working-when-rootscope-value-is-changed)

**Basically** the solution there tells **NOT TO** use `$watch` as it is very heavy solution. **Instead** they propose to use `$emit` and `$on`.

My problem was to *watch* a variable in my **service** and react in **directive**. And with the above method it very easy!

My module/service example:

```
angular.module('xxx').factory('example', function ($rootScope) {
    var user;

    return {
        setUser: function (aUser) {
            user = aUser;
            $rootScope.$emit('user:change');
        },
        getUser: function () {
            return (user) ? user : false;
        },
        ...
    };
});
```

So basically I *watch* my `user`  - whenever it is set to new value I `$emit` a `user:change` status.

Now in my case, in the *directive* I used:

```
angular.module('xxx').directive('directive', function (Auth, $rootScope) {
    return {
        ...
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            ...
            $rootScope.$on('user:change', update);
        }
    };
});
```

Now in the *directive* I listen on the `$rootScope` and **on** the given change - I react respectively. Very easy and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

A wee bit ugly, but I've added registration of scope variables to my service for a toggle:

```
myApp.service('myService', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.value = false;
    self.c2 = function(){};
    self.callback = function(){
        self.value = !self.value; 
       self.c2();
    };

    self.on = function(){
        return self.value;
    };

    self.register = function(obj, key){ 
        self.c2 = function(){
            obj[key] = self.value; 
            obj.$apply();
        } 
    };

    return this;
});
```

And then in the controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.myVar = false;
    myService.register($scope, 'myVar');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. A little question: why do you return `this` from that service instead of `self`?

Comment: Because mistakes get made sometimes. ;-)

Comment: Good practice to `return this;` out of your constructors ;-)

Answer (score 1):

// service: (nothing special here)

```
myApp.service('myService', function() {
  return { someVariable:'abc123' };
});
```

// ctrl:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, myService) {

  $scope.someVariable = myService.someVariable;

  // watch the service and update this ctrl...
  $scope.$watch(function(){
    return myService.someVariable;
  }, function(newValue){
    $scope.someVariable = newValue;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this plunker:: this is the simplest example i could think of

http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName"><!-- Input entered here -->
        <br>Input is : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong><!-- Successfully updates here -->
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        Input should also be here: {{Data.FirstName}}<!-- How do I automatically updated it here? -->
    </div>
</div>



// declare the app with no dependencies
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
   return { FirstName: '' };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some terrible observer patterns here that cause memory leaks on large applications.

I might be a little late but it's as simple as this.

The watch function watches for reference changes (primitive types) if you want to watch something like array push simply use:

`someArray.push(someObj); someArray = someArray.splice(0);`

This will update the reference and update the watch from anywhere. Including a services getter method.
Anything that's a primitive will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the part but I found a nicer way to do this than the answer posted above. Instead of assigning a variable to hold the value of the service variable, I created a function attached to the scope, that returns the service variable.

**controller**

```
$scope.foo = function(){
 return aService.foo;
}
```

I think this will do what you want. My controller keeps checking the value of my service with this implementation. Honestly, this is much simpler than the selected answer.

Comment: why it was downvoted.. I have also used similar technique many times and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have written two simple utility services that help me track service properties changes.

If you want to skip the long explanation, you can go strait to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxkovalov/xcr5q70x/)

1. WatchObj

```js
mod.service('WatchObj', ['$rootScope', WatchObjService]);

function WatchObjService($rootScope) {
  // returns watch function
  // obj: the object to watch for
  // fields: the array of fields to watch
  // target: where to assign changes (usually it's $scope or controller instance)
  // $scope: optional, if not provided $rootScope is use
  return function watch_obj(obj, fields, target, $scope) {
    $scope = $scope || $rootScope;
    //initialize watches and create an array of "unwatch functions"
    var watched = fields.map(function(field) {
      return $scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return obj[field];
        },
        function(new_val) {
          target[field] = new_val;
        }
      );
    });
    //unregister function will unregister all our watches
    var unregister = function unregister_watch_obj() {
      watched.map(function(unregister) {
        unregister();
      });
    };
    //automatically unregister when scope is destroyed
    $scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
    return unregister;
  };
}
```

This service is used in the controller in the following way: 
Suppose you have a service "testService" with the properties 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'. You want to watch and assign to scope 'prop1' and 'prop2'. With the watch service it will look like that:

```js
app.controller('TestWatch', ['$scope', 'TestService', 'WatchObj', TestWatchCtrl]);

function TestWatchCtrl($scope, testService, watch) {
  $scope.prop1 = testService.prop1;
  $scope.prop2 = testService.prop2;
  $scope.prop3 = testService.prop3;
  watch(testService, ['prop1', 'prop2'], $scope, $scope);
}
```

2. apply
   Watch obj is great, but it is not enough if you have asynchronous code in your service. For that case,  I use a second utility which looks like that:

```js
mod.service('apply', ['$timeout', ApplyService]);

function ApplyService($timeout) {
  return function apply() {
    $timeout(function() {});
  };
}
```

I would trigger it in the end of my async code to trigger the $digest loop.
Like that:

```js
app.service('TestService', ['apply', TestService]);

function TestService(apply) {
  this.apply = apply;
}
TestService.prototype.test3 = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.prop1 = 'changed_test_2';
    this.prop2 = 'changed2_test_2';
    this.prop3 = 'changed3_test_2';
    this.apply(); //trigger $digest loop
  }.bind(this));
}
```

So, all of that together will look like that (you can run it or [open fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxkovalov/xcr5q70x/)):

```js
// TEST app code

var app = angular.module('app', ['watch_utils']);

app.controller('TestWatch', ['$scope', 'TestService', 'WatchObj', TestWatchCtrl]);

function TestWatchCtrl($scope, testService, watch) {
  $scope.prop1 = testService.prop1;
  $scope.prop2 = testService.prop2;
  $scope.prop3 = testService.prop3;
  watch(testService, ['prop1', 'prop2'], $scope, $scope);
  $scope.test1 = function() {
    testService.test1();
  };
  $scope.test2 = function() {
    testService.test2();
  };
  $scope.test3 = function() {
    testService.test3();
  };
}

app.service('TestService', ['apply', TestService]);

function TestService(apply) {
  this.apply = apply;
  this.reset();
}
TestService.prototype.reset = function() {
  this.prop1 = 'unchenged';
  this.prop2 = 'unchenged2';
  this.prop3 = 'unchenged3';
}
TestService.prototype.test1 = function() {
  this.prop1 = 'changed_test_1';
  this.prop2 = 'changed2_test_1';
  this.prop3 = 'changed3_test_1';
}
TestService.prototype.test2 = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.prop1 = 'changed_test_2';
    this.prop2 = 'changed2_test_2';
    this.prop3 = 'changed3_test_2';
  }.bind(this));
}
TestService.prototype.test3 = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.prop1 = 'changed_test_2';
    this.prop2 = 'changed2_test_2';
    this.prop3 = 'changed3_test_2';
    this.apply();
  }.bind(this));
}
//END TEST APP CODE

//WATCH UTILS
var mod = angular.module('watch_utils', []);

mod.service('apply', ['$timeout', ApplyService]);

function ApplyService($timeout) {
  return function apply() {
    $timeout(function() {});
  };
}

mod.service('WatchObj', ['$rootScope', WatchObjService]);

function WatchObjService($rootScope) {
  // target not always equals $scope, for example when using bindToController syntax in 
  //directives
  return function watch_obj(obj, fields, target, $scope) {
    // if $scope is not provided, $rootScope is used
    $scope = $scope || $rootScope;
    var watched = fields.map(function(field) {
      return $scope.$watch(
        function() {
          return obj[field];
        },
        function(new_val) {
          target[field] = new_val;
        }
      );
    });
    var unregister = function unregister_watch_obj() {
      watched.map(function(unregister) {
        unregister();
      });
    };
    $scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
    return unregister;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class='test' ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestWatch">
  prop1: {{prop1}}
  <br>prop2: {{prop2}}
  <br>prop3 (unwatched): {{prop3}}
  <br>
  <button ng-click="test1()">
    Simple props change
  </button>
  <button ng-click="test2()">
    Async props change
  </button>
  <button ng-click="test3()">
    Async props change with apply
  </button>
</div>
```