# Value not updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular and still struggling with basics.

I've a cart icon in my menu with the preset value to 0 at first load.

In the product list I have a button to every product to say 'AddToCart'. 
So what I want is-

I want to update the cart value whenever I click to `AddToCart` button. However initial value of cart is being setup by angular, But I am not able to update it further.

Here is the code-

```
var app = angular.module("productsApp", [])
.factory("sharedService", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        var sharedServiceRef = {
            cart: 0,
            setCartValue: function (product) {
                if (product) {
                    this.cart = this.cart + 1;
                    sharedServiceRef.cart = this.cart;
                }
                else {
                    sharedServiceRef.cart = 0;
                }
                console.log(sharedServiceRef.cart);
            }
        };
        return sharedServiceRef;
    }]);


function ProductListController($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.addItemToCart = function (product) {
        sharedService.setCartValue(product);
    }
}

function CartController($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.cart = sharedService.cart;
}
```

At initial load of page it sets the value of cart in the view-

```
<div ng-controller="CartController">
       {{cart}}
    </div>
```

And when I change the value in another controller and set it -

```
function ProductListController($scope, sharedService) {
    $scope.addItemToCart = function (product) {
        sharedService.setCartValue(product);
    }
}
```

It doesn't update the cart value, It remains 0 at first place.

How do I update a value in angular?

**Edit**
This is my view from where add button is being called-

```
<div ng-controller="ProductListController">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <span>
            $ {{product.salePrice}}
        </span>
        <div>
            <a ng-click="addItemToCart(product)">
                Add To Cart
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the html side of things for the cart please?

Comment: can this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800454/angularjs-the-correct-way-of-binding-to-a-service-properties

Comment: @JohnMc, Please see now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error was not an angular error but a javascript one.

When you do this: 
`$scope.cart = sharedService.cart;`

you are assigning the value not a reference, in other words it is a copy of the original values, changes done to `sharedService.cart` will not affect the variable `$scope.cart`

In javascript primitive variables are assigned by value value while objects by reference, so what you can do is assign an object to `$scope.cart`

Here is a plunker with an example of it working
https://plnkr.co/edit/MKSofFcgEWMjwQaOvLsP?p=preview

Comment: Just a minute, So you mean to say object reference is what is bound internally, not the object itself. Right?

Comment: Here is a very good explanation about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language