# AngularJS bind a value in a factory to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to link two controllers via a factory. I want to set up a pointer in one controller to a value `myFactoryVar` on the factory so that when the value in the factory changes, the value `controllerVar` in the controller changes.
I've read this post and several like it [AngularJS : The correct way of binding to a service properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800454/angularjs-the-correct-way-of-binding-to-a-service-properties)
but I can't seem to make it work with my code. Maybe it's the format? Maybe I'm binding to a primitive type without meaning to. Here is what I've got so far, any idea how to make it work as intended?

Controller 1:

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .controller('MyCtrl1', MyCtrl1);

    function MyCtrl1(myTracker) {

        var vm = this;

        angular.extend(vm, {
            controllerVar: myTracker.myFactoryVar,
            myTrackerVarIncrement: myTrackerVarIncrement

        });

        function myTrackerVarIncrement() {
            myTracker.myFactoryVarIncrement();
            /* should log the same value as myFactoryVar but doesn't */
            console.log(vm.controllerVar);
        }
    }
})();
```

Controller 2:

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .controller('MyCtrl2', MyCtrl2);

    function MyCtrl2(myTracker) {
        var vm = this;

        angular.extend(vm, {
            myTrackerVarIncrement: myTrackerVarIncrement
        });


        function myTrackerVarIncrement() {
            /* I want to be able to increment the value in the factory, */
            /* and by means of that, the value in the other controller too */
            myTracker.myFactoryVarIncrement();
        }

    }
})();
```

Factory:

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .factory('myTracker', myTracker);

    function myTracker() {

        var factory = {
            myFactoryVar: 1,
            myFactoryVarIncrement: myFactoryVarIncrement
        };

        return factory;

        function myFactoryVarIncrement() {
            factory.myFactoryVar += 1;
        }

    }
})();
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe I'm binding to a primitive type without meaning to.

The `myFactoryVar` is a property of an object. Share the reference of the object of which it is a property.

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myapp')
        .controller('MyCtrl1', MyCtrl1);

    function MyCtrl1(myTracker) {

        var vm = this;

        angular.extend(vm, {
            //controllerVar: myTracker.myFactoryVar,
            controllerRef: myTracker,
            myTrackerVarIncrement: myTrackerVarIncrement

        });

        function myTrackerVarIncrement() {
            myTracker.myFactoryVarIncrement();
            /* should log the same value as myFactoryVar but doesn't */
            //console.log(vm.controllerVar);
            console.log(vm.controllerRef.myFactoryVar);
        }
    }
})();
```

Bind to the *reference* to share the *contents*.

Comment: This was it. Everything is working as expected now. Thank you.