# AngularJS update shared data in a Service from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please see this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oKPdKN?p=preview). I have a `myApp.common.sharedata` module to share data between two modules `myApp.interactive.layout.menu` and `myApp.interactive.layout.chart`.

If you click the checkbox in the  `menu` module, it will call service `sharedata.check(key);` to update the shared data.

In `common/sharedata/sharedata.service.js` function `sharedata.check`. I use `sharedata.series = response.data.data;` to update the data from $http, it is not working. The data is not synchronized to module `myApp.interactive.layout.menu` and `myApp.interactive.layout.chart`. I also tried `sharedata.series = angular.copy(response.data.data);`, it is not working too. I have to do

```
for(var i=0; i<response.data.data.length;i++){
    sharedata.series[i] = response.data.data[i];
}
```

Any suggestions? My ultimate goal is to use $http to initialize the shared data in module `myApp.common.sharedata`. Now I'm using the static code. If I use

```
$http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users")
  .then(function(response) {
  sharedata.series = (response.data.data);
});
```

The data does not synchronized to module `myApp.interactive.layout.menu` and `myApp.interactive.layout.chart` too.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/LCPWiSJkKzyxDVvKWgGT?p=preview - factory change should be updated into each controller. you need to either poke them with $emit approach or watch the `sharedata.series` on each controller so they can be updated with new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small issue which you need to fix.

Change your `InteractiveChartCtrl` as following.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.interactive.layout.chart', ['myApp.common.sharedata'])

.controller('InteractiveChartCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedata',function($scope,sharedata) {

        $scope.menuSeries = sharedata; //MODIFIED HERE

        $scope.$watch('menuSeries', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('menuSeries changed');
            console.log(newValue);
        },true);

}]);
```

I have changed  `$scope.menuSeries = sharedata; //MODIFIED HERE`

And your `chart.html` as following.

```
<div>
    <div>
            <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in menuSeries.series" class="list-group-item">
                        <label class="interactive_chart_metrics">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="metrics" id="{{item.id}}" ng-click="seriesMenuClick($event,checkStatus)" ng-model='checkStatus' ng-checked ="item.selected" alt="{{item.first_name}}">&nbsp;{{item.first_name}}</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    <div>
        {{menuSeries}}
    </div>

</div>
```

I have changed here <`li ng-repeat="item in menuSeries.series" class="list-group-item">`

This will fix the issue.
Check the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/e6yOf12KSOMEIPLA9Cv4?p=preview).

Updated for [Menu](https://plnkr.co/edit/5CA1O5lEGj4Dw9G4OhAg?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! But the data in `Module: Menu` does not change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apply the same approach

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the reason? What's the difference between `sharedata` and `sharedata.series`?

Comment: Please see this https://plnkr.co/edit/lhA1Ki?p=preview , I created a getter function `getSeries` in sharedata service. I can not get data synchronized to  menu and chart modules.  My question is why only use `sharedata` works? Why can't I use `sharedata.series` or the getter function? Thanks!

Comment: @Tester can you have a look to this answer, it might help you to understand this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441020/297322

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand `$scope.menuSeries = sharedata;` provide 2 way binding. `$scope.menuSeries = sharedata.series;` will not do that. I'm still learning AngularJS. Can you tell me how should I learn? I have tried the official tutorial and John Papa's style guide.