# Invoke function between two controllers while using routeprovider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, route-provider

I am using route provider as follows,

```
var appModule = angular.module('ngLogin', ['ngRoute','restangular','btford.socket-io','ngSanitize','xeditable']);

appModule.config(['$routeProvider',
              function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                when('/home', {
                  templateUrl: 'sample/homepage.html',
                    controller: 'ngHomeControl'
                    }).
                when('/contacts', {
                  templateUrl: 'sample/homepage.html',
                    controller: 'ngContactControl'
                  });
            }]);
```

Here I need to call function from `ngHomeControl` to `ngContactControl`.

I tried as follows, but the function didn't invoked.

```
appModule.controller('ngHomeControl', function($scope,$routeParams,socket,Restangular,$http) {

$rootScope.$broadcast('getFriendList',{"userName":userName});

});

appModule.controller('ngContactControl', function($scope,$routeParams,$rootScope,socket,sharedProperties,Restangular,$http,$timeout) {

$scope.$on("getFriendList",function(event,data)
        {
          console.log('getFriendList');
        });
});
```

Can anyone help me to resolve?

Comment: Proper way of doing this would be with a use of a `service` which would return list of friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work as only one controller is instantiated at a time (in your case).

A proper way would be to use a service. There is a nice [article](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/) that wil help you with this.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470509/617996) on how to create a service.

Based on those two resources you should came up with something similar to this:

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', ['ngRoute']);

appModule.config(['$routeProvider',
              function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                when('/home', {
                  templateUrl: 'home.html',
                    controller: 'ngHomeControl'
                    }).
                when('/contacts', {
                  templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
                    controller: 'ngContactControl'
                  });
            }]);

appModule.service('friendsService', function(){
    this.getFriendList = function () {
        return ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];
    }
});

appModule.controller('ngHomeControl', function($scope, friendsService) {
    $scope.homeFriends = friendsService.getFriendList();
});

appModule.controller('ngContactControl', function($scope, friendsService) {
    $scope.contactFriends = friendsService.getFriendList();
});
```

There is a complete working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qg3nf/1/) so you can test it out.
Please also checkout the console output to see when used components are instantiated.

You will see that controllers are instantiated each time the route changes - they are instantiated implicitly via the `ngController` directive used inside templates. The service is instantiated only once and this is at the time when it is needed/injected for the first time.

Comment: How can I use `$scope` inside service?

Comment: And also am using restangular inside the service, if I `return` the restangular's `response` value, it wont reflect. which means return value can't assign to the `$scope.homeFriends`. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your event listener isn't fired is because there isn't a `ngContactControl` instance alive when your at `/home`. You can create a parent controller, which handles the scope events but a better way is to use a service that is shared among the controllers that need this functionality.

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bNJtOP?p=preview) for an example how to share data and/or functions via a service.