# AngularJS Update Scope $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So recently I've been updating something that looks like the below:

```
$scope.arrayOfThings = [];

function setArrayOfThings() {
     thingsService.get().then(function (things) {
         $scope.arrayOfThings = things;
     });
}

$scope.$on('arrayOfThings.add', setArrayOfThings);
```

To look more like this (using the lesser-known promise integration into bindings...):

```
$scope.arrayOfThings = thingsService.get();
```

But how do I force `arrayOfThings` to update (or re-resolve?) when the collection is changed from another `$scope`?

Comment: I believe `thingsService` is implemented using `$resource`?

Comment: @sza partially - offline storage and `$http`.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing it than this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables

Comment: I went with the `registerObserver` pattern (for now). http://stackoverflow.com/a/18569315/491468

Answer (score 0):

arrayOfThings can be seen only inside a child scope, so any change of arrayOfThings in a child scope will maintain data-binding anyway. The data-binding has to be resolve manually by $scope.$apply if the arrayOfThing is changed from an event (DOM event, $broadcast, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a watch on the service call thingsService.get in the controller that you want to be notified of a change. Like this:

```
$scope.$watch(thingsService.get, function(newVal, oldVal){
  $scope.arrayOfThings2 = newVal;  
} );
```

This is assuming you are injecting that service into the new controller.

Comment: Causes a digest exception - also this wouldn't work for methods with parameters?

Comment: Hmm. There must be something else going on. I have used this a lot to react to data changes in services. Sure, you can pass parameters into the service call if you want.