# How to access Angular service object from template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have 2 controllers: one for menu(dynamic list of elements we can add/remove) and one for ng-view.

I need to access menu elements from ng-view controller.
So, as I understand it right, I should create service so menu objects will be available in any controller, I need just to inject it.

Done.

But!

I need these objects in rendering. So, I should put menu elements in scope of both controllers? That's ugly: I should update it's value each time I update elements in service. Damn.

So, currently it works with rootScope and service, which has method to deal with elements list update/add/remove AJAX. But I think something is wrong here.

Any advices?

Comment: You could use an Angular 'value' and inject that into both.  I have also just assigned a service to a scope property and referenced a property of the service directly in my template. (e.g {{$scope.myService.someProperty}})

Comment: @CraigSquire, I'm not sure is it good idea to assign service into $scope, because it will be fully checked in AngularJS $digest loop. I don't need that. But value... it is good, but damn... why not rootScope? So we should create app.value for each service(e.g. similar situation)?

Comment: Sure, maybe just watch a property of the service which references an object.  $scope.myData = $scope.myService.myData and reference $scope.myData.someProperty in your template.  Not sure what you mean by app.value for each service.  It is also acceptable to store data on $rootScope, yes.  I typically don't do that because it can become a dumping ground when you don't know where else to put something.

Comment: Could you share some code in plunker? Might not need a service but shouldn't use global scope as it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/yLjqgJCdjwUf3WSg1P4Y?p=preview

Comment: @CraigSquire I wonder, can I use function instead of object? So it will check for reference, returned in function... For value per service I mean cases, when I have few services and I wanna use it's data to display some things.

Answer (score 3):

If all you have is data then you can use a Value.  Inject the Value into each of your controllers and store it on your scope, then reference a property of the Value in your template.  If you use a Service, you can do pretty much the exact same thing.  My example shows one solution using each.

See this example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qTbSjnf6Q2FVDurGZhKd

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="mainVal.value"></input>
  <input ng-model="mainSvcVal.value"></input>
</div>
<div ng-controller="OtherCtrl">
  <input ng-model="otherVal.value"></input>
  <input ng-model="otherSvcVal.value"></input>
</div>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.value('MyValue', {value: "Hello There"});

app.service('MyService', function() {
  this.myData = {
    value: "Goodbye"
  }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, MyValue, MyService) {
  $scope.mainVal = MyValue;
  $scope.mainSvcVal = MyService.myData;
});

app.controller('OtherCtrl', function($scope, MyValue, MyService) {
  $scope.otherVal = MyValue;
  $scope.otherSvcVal = MyService.myData;
});
```

One thing to note would be if you reassign MyService.myData to a new object, it would break the relationship.

Comment: It looks good, but I'm not sure. So, if we need to create service, we should create app.value to store it's data too? Why not just service? So what's a purpose of service?

Comment: A 'value' is just a service that you can assign a primitive, existing object or function to, instead of using a factory or constructor function as you do when you create a 'service'.  A 'service' can also store data. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/$provide

Comment: I found a similar question with other ways as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables

Comment: I can't use idea with service data reference. Because it will be replaced with new object each time. Can I use function to get it?

Comment: Use a $watch on the service property.

Comment: But what if I have more than one property? Data, page, total, sort, selected counter, etc. Will it be huge overhead?

Comment: Are all of your properties in one object?  There are 3 kinds of 'watch'.  $watch (not deep) just watches for the object reference to change, $watch (deep) watches for anything in that object to change or $watchCollection is in between and will watch for the object reference or the top level properties to change.  One of those should work.  Unless you use a lot of deep watches on your page, there won't be any performance problems.  Can you update your plunker with an example of "real data" with all those properties you list?

Comment: Check out this blog post and try his github demo.  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-Scope-watch-vs-watchCollection-In-AngularJS.htm

Comment: wow! Thank you so much. It looks really good. But one question: what is about default angular bindings? It uses $watch(true) way, $watchCollection or $watch() way? Just curious.