# watch does not trigger when service variable updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to change variable in service but watch in controller does not trigger when that happens:

```
app.factory 'User',  ->
  class User
    status: 'offline'
    set_status: (status) ->
      @status = status

app.service 'Account', ->
  dsa: null
  test: 'asd'
  user: null

app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope, $timeout, Account, User) ->
  Account.user = new User
  $scope.$watch Account.user.status, (status) ->
    console.log "status changed to #{status}"

  $timeout ->
    Account.user.set_status 'busy'
    console.log Account.user.status
  , 2000
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mCdw2YSws3yIAdkq88Sk) for this. What is the reason?

Comment: Have a look at this answer for the correct approach in this kind of scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables

Comment: @maurizio There's nothing wrong with using $watch, no need to go the observer pattern unless it really is necessary.

Comment: @maurizio, I also don't like idea of using observer but in my case there is definitely something wrong with $watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with $watch. The $watch expression is evaluated against the scope it is called on and takes a string expression or a function as its first argument. To get it to work either publish `Account` inside your controller to scope and $watch on it via string:

[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q3o3y7nz9bCKwmLIMvoQ)

```
app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope, $timeout, Account, User) ->
  $scope.name = 'World'
  console.log Account
  Account.user = new User
  $scope.Account = Account
  $scope.$watch 'Account.user.status', (status) ->
    console.log "status changed to #{status}"

  $timeout ->
    Account.user.set_status 'busy'
    console.log Account.user.status
  , 2000
```

Or alternatively change the watch expression to a function that returns your Account.user.status property. I'm not familiar with coffee script so I'll leave the example up to you.

Comment: Thanx man. I thought I can use it without exposing the service variables to the scope and that was my mistake....