# accessing multiple variables / obj / funcs etc within a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very inexperienced with angularjs. I am trying to implement a service to access data across controllers. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/exclsr/3595424) example.

Below is my js. I haven't posted my HTML because I am just trying to get the logic working within the js first.

```
angular.module('App')
    .factory('TestService', function() {
        return {testVar : '22222'}
    })

    .controller('MainCtrl', function (TestService) {
        console.log(TestService.testVar);
    }
    .controller('SecCtrl', function (TestService) {
        console.log(TestService.testVar);
    }
```

This works fine. I console log '22222' each time I access both controllers. I can update the var and it is updated fine between controllers. If I replace `return {testVar : '22222'}` with

```
return {
   testVar : { x : '22222' }
}
```

Then I get the object `x : '2222'` logged to console. Which again seems fine.

The thing is I can't really understand the *usage* of `TestService.testVar` in the console log. At first glance I thought it was logging the var testVar from service TestService. From looking at the example however, it is apparent that testVar in this case is actually a key and what is returned is the key value.

Is this the only way to return something from a service, as the key value?

I wish to use the service to access **multiple** values/objects etc within the service but the use of return in the example only returns the one variable obviously; unless I use if statements, but that seems a little over the top and like I'm really missing something with the use of controllers...

Something like;

```
angular.module('App')
    .factory('TestService', function() {
        (..code to choose what to return but the proper way...)
        return {testVar : '22222'}
        return {testVar2 : '333333'}
    })

    .controller('MainCtrl', function (TestService) {
        console.log(TestService.testVar);
        console.log(TestService.testVar2);
    }
    .controller('SecCtrl', function (TestService) {
        console.log(TestService.testVar);
        console.log(TestService.testVar2);
    }
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables) question, but i think it's more complicated than what I am asking.

Comment: Don't forget semicolons

Comment: One return with two keys: `testVar` and `testVar2`

Comment: @krzysztof thanks, this works. But if I have many variables within the services I wish to access, does that mean I always have to return ALL the keys each time? Seems inefficient

Comment: @myol, no, I will improve my answer to show other possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First iteration

We can use **service/factory** to store infromation and retrive it in controllers.

```
angular.module('app', []).service('testService', function() {
    var testService = {};
    testService.x = 'x';
    testService.y = 'y';
    return testService;
}).controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, testService) {
    $scope.x = testService.x;
    $scope.y = testService.y;
}).controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, testService) {
    $scope.x = testService.x;
    $scope.y = testService.y;
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/aomL09fd/

### Second iteration

We can use **service/factory** to share infromation between controllers.

```
angular.module('app', []).service('testService', function() {
    var testService = {
        someObject: {
            x: 'x',
            y: 'y',
            z: ''
        }
    };
    return testService;
}).controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, testService) {
    $scope.someObject = testService.someObject;
}).controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, testService) {
    $scope.someObject = testService.someObject;
});
```

Please take a look that I’m returing object `someObject` and rest is made by Angular diggest.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krzysztof_safjanowski/aomL09fd/1/

Comment: Thanks. I still don't quite understand the use of controllers completely, but this gives me a much more solid base to work off.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
angular.module('App')
    .factory('TestService', function() {
        // Code to choose what to return but the proper way
        return {testVar2 : '333333', testVar : '22222'}
    })
```