# AngularJS parent directive communicate with child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider two nested directives with isolate scopes:

```
<dctv1>
    <dctv2></dctv2>
<dctv1>
```

**If I want `dctv2` to talk to `dctv1` I have may options:**

1. I may require the controller of `dctv1` in the definition of `dctv2` using the `require:'^dctv1'`
2. I may call an expression on the parent scope with the wrapper `<dctv2 callParent="hello()"></dctv2>` and `scope:{callParent:'&'}`
3. I can also use `$scope.$emit` in `dctv2` but then all parent scopes will hear the message.

**Now I want `dctv1` to talk to `dctv2`.**

1. The only way I may accomplish this is to use `$scope.$broadcast`, but then all children will hear.

By talk to here i mean call a function or similar. Don't want to set up watches clogging the digestloop.

How can I make `dctv1` notify `dctv2` in the best way, making them loose-coupled? I should just be able to remove dctv2 without errors.

Comment: If you chose the events. You can call preventDefault and stopPropagation. In fact $event is an instance of jQuery event.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [AngularJS NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) for some ideas.

Each `<dctv2>` directive would require `<dvtv1>` to have it's controller injected. You can then add objects or callbacks to properties of that controller, and remove them when `<dctv2>` is destroyed.

`<dvtv1>` would not talk directly to children, but would trigger callbacks bound to it's properties.

For example;

`NgModelController` has `$parsers` and `$formatters` that are an array of function callbacks. You push your own functions into the array to extend that controllers behavior.

When `NgModelController` performs input validation it's basically talking to other directives via these properties.

Comment: I support the main idea with the callback (each dctv2 instance will register its own callback), but I would leave NgModelController aside.

Comment: @Benjamin can you elaborate your idea further?

Comment: @Wei-jye I just don't think that `NgModelController` is a good example here.  I'd suggest using `require:'^dctv1'` to get a reference to the parent controller. Then, register to that parent (`dctv1.registerChild(self)`). Afterwards, dctv1 knows its children and can interact with them.

Comment: @Benjamin Yes I just did that. I used this method to do event registration and raise event.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [angular services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). That way you can decouple your behavior into one or more services.

Take a look at this also : [AngularJS : How to watch service variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/how-to-watch-service-variables)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a Service/Factory that will communicate with the controllers that you want.

**For example, here's a getter/setter Factory**

```
.factory('factoryName', function () {

    var something = "Hello";

    return {

        get: function () {
            return something;
        },

        set: function (keyword) {
            something = keyword;
            return something ;
        }
    };

}])
```

**And then in your controllers:**

```
.controller('controllerOne', ['factoryName', function (factoryName) {
    $scope.test = factoryName.get();
}]);

.controller('controllerTwo', ['factoryName', function (factoryName) {
    $scope.test = factoryName.get();
    $scope.clickThis = function (keyword) {
        factoryName.set(keyword);
    };
}]);
```

I suggest reading up on this : [Can one controller call another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293423/can-one-controller-call-another)

Answer (score -1):

You can manage it using an id for each child that have to be passed to the parent; the parent will broadcast back the event using that id: the child will do the action only if the id passed from the parent is the his own.

Bye