# View doesn't get updated from Service

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display an object (songTitle) from my service. The initial state (tmp) is displayed. If I am changing the object in the service, the view doesnt get updated.

Js:

```
var party = angular.module("party", []);

party.run(function () {
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
});

party.service('PlayerService', function ($window) {
      this.playlist = [
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnW2uLwHAas",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPT8DA32U6U",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGjEnfQl37s",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFtTY2S20mI",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmXQiPLoLTk",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbVx85DS9zc",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciidn3nEoiE",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm0DgkBEnUI",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2OCSWF7sAw",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_-giRHtuv8",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPT8DA32U6U",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGjEnfQl37s",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFtTY2S20mI",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmXQiPLoLTk",
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbVx85DS9zc"
      ];
      this.player = {};
      this.pbTimer = null;
      this.songTitle = "tmp";

      $window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
            this.player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                  height: '100',
                  width: '100',
                  videoId: 'ciidn3nEoiE',
                  events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady
                  }
            });
      }


      function onPlayerReady() {
            console.log("db ready");
            songTitle = player.getVideoData().title;
            console.log(songTitle);
      }

      this.playVideo = function (url) {
            console.log("db playVideo " + url);
            player.loadVideoById(url.split("watch\?v=")[1], 0, "large");
            console.log(player);

      }

});
party.controller("FrontController", function ($scope) {
      $scope.front = {};
      $scope.front.title = "PARTY";
});

party.controller("PartyController", ['$scope', 'PlayerService', function ($scope, PlayerService) {
      $scope.party = {};
      $scope.party.title = "PARTY";
      Sortable.create(playlist, { /* options */ });
      $scope.playlist = PlayerService.playlist;
      $scope.playVideo = function (url) {
            PlayerService.playVideo(url);
      }
      $scope.songTitle = PlayerService.songTitle;
}]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="party">
<div ng-controller="PartyController" class="container-fluid">
...
    <p id="playertitle">{{songTitle}}</p>
...
```

Log:

```
db ready 
Blackmill Feat. Veela - Life (Full Version)
```

Comment: `songTitle` is not the same as `this. songTitle`

Comment: even if i write this.songTitle = player.getVideoData().title; it doesnt work

Comment: Inside your service, you should be returning an object with references to variables and functions that you want, like this: `return { var: var }` That way, you can access it from the controllers like Service.var

Comment: Where is the code where `songTitle` is actually assigned a new value ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `onPlayerReady` function. The line `songTitle = player.getVideoData().title;` doesn't set `songTitle` on your service, but rather on the global scope, which is the `window` object. Simply using `this.songTitle` won't help either, because `this` doesn't refer to your service too in the scope of `onPlayerReady`.

The easiest solution would be to save a reference to your service outside of `onPlayerReady` and then use it to assign `songTitle`:

```
var self = this;
function onPlayerReady() {
  console.log("db ready");
  self.songTitle = player.getVideoData().title;
  console.log(self.songTitle);
}
```

Still, this is not enough. Because you change `songTitle` from outside the Angular world (the Youtube player callbacks), you need to call `$scope.$apply` to notify Angular something has changed.

For that, you need to inject $rootScope into your service:

```
party.service('PlayerService', function ($window, $rootScope)
```

and change `songTitle` using `$rootScope.$apply`:

```
var self = this;
function onPlayerReady() {
  console.log("db ready");
  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    self.songTitle = player.getVideoData().title;
    console.log(self.songTitle);
  });
}
```

Comment: your answer seems legit, but the title still wont be updated on the view. I added the log to the playvideo function, which will be called aftter onPlayerReady. I see that the object is updated, but the old value is still shown on the view

Comment: still doens't work, i guess that angular doesnt recogniese that change. I guess I have to use some solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/how-to-watch-service-variables?lq=1