# AngularJS bind variable from service to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Can I bind only variable (not object) from service to controller?

For bind object, it works (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32510545/2442133)):

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl1">
  1st Controller
  <input type="text" ng-model="model1.prop1"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="model1.prop2"/>
</div>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
  2nd Controller
  <input type="text" ng-model="model2.prop1"/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="model2.prop2"/>
</div>

app.service('dataService', function() {
  this.model = {
    'prop1': '',
    'prop2': ''
  };
});

app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.model1 = dataService.model;
});


app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.model2 = dataService.model;
});
```

[Demo plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uqrqCQVZRGQCWNQJnnW7).

But I need only one variable (not object with properties).

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl1">
  1st Controller
  <input type="text" ng-model="variable1"/>
</div>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
  2nd Controller
  <input type="text" ng-model="variable2"/>
</div>

app.service('dataService', function() {
  this.variable = '';
});

app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.variable1 = dataService.variable;
});


app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.variable2 = dataService.variable;
});
```

[Demo plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V6YbaQkshGSnGl9S7232).

It don't work. Why?

Is there nice way to this (without object with only one property or without `$watch`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work by setting the scope variable to the `dataService` object *reference* and the `ng-model` attributes to the *reference* property.

JS

```
app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.ds1 = dataService;
});

app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.ds2 = dataService;
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl1">
  1st Controller
  <input type="text" ng-model="ds1.variable"/>
</div>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
  2nd Controller
  <input type="text" ng-model="ds2.variable"/>
</div>
```

The rule of thumb with `ng-model` is always include a "dot".

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/o52Ei9ktEORLwf9cdNzK?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an object like so:
[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yMjEAhjk5ZwNYlgClQsC?p=preview)

```
app.service('dataService', function() {
    this.variable = {a:''};
});
```

Comment: It's object with one property (a bit ugly solution if I need only one variable, but I have no other choice probably).