# angularjs- How to call the other controller in app.controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, iframe

I want to see that 2 contorller called by 1 contorller.
How to make it call? PS. B is in the iframe tag.
Please help me.

now html source structure

```
A.html (A.js) 
B.html (B.js) A children tag -  iframe
```

now js source (A.js)

```
var app = angular.module('upload',[nUpload]); //nUpload is other module 
app.controller('upload',[$scope,nupload,
function($scope,nupload){           //nupload is service of nUpload module 
            .... //fileupload 
}]);                         ----- **1contorller**
```

B.js (js file is in the other html tag (iframe))

```
var app = angular.module('progress',['']);</br>
app.controller('progress',[$scope,,,,] function($scope,,){
          ... //draw progress } 
);                   ----- **2contorller**
```

I dream of sources (A.js)

```
app.controller('upload',,,,
function(,,,){
    B.progress = "10%"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm.. to share objects between controllers you need an factory.

Try this:

A.js

```
var app = angular.module('upload',[nUpload,'container']);

app.controller('upload',[$scope,nupload,'Progress',
function($scope,nupload,Progress){
    Progress.setProgress("10%");
}]);
```

B.js

```
var app = angular.module('progress',['container']);

app.controller('progress',[$scope,'Progress',,, function($scope,Progress){
  var progressData = Progress.getProgress();

 }]);
```

container.js

```
var app = angular.module('container',[]);

app.factory("Progress",[function(){
   var progress = "0%";
   return {
     getProgress: function() {
        return progress;
     }
     setProgress: function(data) {
        progress = data;
     }
   }
}]);
```

Hope this help you.

;D

Comment: Thank you so much! @Javierif :)

Comment: if function called by A.js (Progress.setProgress)

Comment: when function called by A.js (Progress.setProgress),can i update or  binding various of B.js ?.. i still don't know angular js framework....:( help me angle!!

Comment: just like this source{setProgress: function(data) {
        progress = data;
        var ifr = parent.document.getElementById('iframeId');
       var doc = ifr.contentWindow || ifr.contentDocument;
       if ( doc.document ) doc =doc.document;                      
       var scope = angular.element( doc.getElementById('ProgressId') ).scope();      
       scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.upload();
       });
     }}

Comment: mmm... u can use $watch to this.. wait i paste a snipet code

Comment: mmm... u can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables
If u need more information how to build this, create a new question in a comment I do not have enough space to write it :P (And comment here with url)