# $scope.$apply after $scope.$on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

I am using the [$broadcast pattern outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863597/1068446) to controllers to listen to their service's state.

for example, here I listen to the service's busy/unbusy state to set the mouse cursor.

```
//Our service
function startRunning(){
     $rootScope.$broadcast("busy"); 
}
function stopRunning(){
     $rootScope.$broadcast("unbusy"); 
}

//Our controller
$scope.$on("busy", function(){
    $scope.state = "busy"; 
}); 

$scope.$on("unbusy", function(){
    $scope.state = "ready"
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller = "myctrl" ng-state = "state"/>
```

CSS:

```
.busy{
    cursor: wait; 
}

.ready {
    cursor:auto; 
}
```

The problem with this is that the cursor doesn't change immediately. It usually requires me to move the mouse, I imagine to trigger the `$digest` cycle, before the cursor changes.

I can fix that with

```
$scope.$apply($scope.state = "ready");
```

But this will throw up:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

errors.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Edit: here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/23512/

The issue appears to be something to do with using non-angular timeout/asynchronous methods.  (ie. issue doesn't appear if using a `$timeout`, but does appear if using a `setTimeout`;

Comment: Suggest you create a simple demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) or other sandbox site that replicates your problem. browser may not react immediately to cursor style change without some movement. Also not clear at all what is triggering your state changes

Comment: Use `$timeout(function(){$scope.$apply('state = "ready"')});`. `$timeout` allows for a "safe apply".

Comment: @charlietfl - Yip, that's what i'm upto now and.... I can't reproduce it. :-/

Comment: $charliefl - I've added a fiddle. It looks like it's something to do with `$timeout` vs `setTimeout`. It looks like the solution will be to wrap my broadcasts in a `$timeout`.

Comment: oh...that wasn't shown in question. `setTimout` isn't in angular context when changing scope

Comment: @charlietfl yeah - the difficulty is that in the actual problem, it's an external JS library where I'm calling the broadcasts from, and so it's hard to tell where/how the context changes. I think the solution is to wrap the broadcasts in a `$timeout`

Comment: Had you mentioned external library from beginning answer would have been easy and quick nd gotten to same point you are now