# Angular: How to keep $scope properties in sync with controller functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller like so:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, items, UserFactory) {
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.changeItems = function (item) {
      // Do something with items, in the UserFactory
      UserFactory.removeItem(items);
    }
  }
```

Where `items` is returned by a `resolve` in the routeProvider.

If `UserFactory.removeItem` operates on something like cookies or localStorage, or changes something on a model, what is the best way to also update `$scope.items`

Should I have the `UserFactory.removeItem` return the new `items`, or should I do something directly in the `$scope.changeItems` function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried observing the changes and doing a callback? Here is a good example how to use them https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558885/5136207

So every time the value in the service is changed you can call the observer function which will lunch a callback to the controllers that are registered and update the values for them.