# How to keep service data the same on multiple controllers without using $watch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There's an older answer I saw here on S.O, which states:

> "This JavaScript works as we are passing an object back from the
>   service rather than a value. When a JavaScript object is returned from
>   a service, Angular adds watches to all of its properties."

It then gives this example:

> JavaScript:
>
> ```
> angular.module("Demo", [])
>     .factory("DemoService", function($timeout) {
>
>         function DemoService() {
>             var self = this;
>             self.name = "Demo Service";
>
>             self.count = 0;
>
>             self.counter = function(){
>                 self.count++;
>                 $timeout(self.counter, 1000);
>             }
>
>             self.addOneHundred = function(){
>                 self.count+=100;
>             }
>
>             self.counter();
>         }
>
>         return new DemoService();
>
>     })
>     .controller("DemoController", function($scope, DemoService) {
>
>         $scope.service = DemoService;
>
>         $scope.minusOneHundred = function() {
>             DemoService.count -= 100;
>         }
>
>     });
> ```
>
> HTML
>
> ```
> <div ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
>     <div>
>         <h4>{{service.name}}</h4>
>         <p>Count: {{service.count}}</p>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

I asked the OP if $watch was necessary to keep the data the same across controllers, and they said "no" without elaborating.

But, when I test it out, the DemoService "count" value is not the same on both controllers, unless I use $watch.

Here's a fiddle with the example below, but with an added controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/qqejytbz/1/

Given this example, how it is possible to keep the value the same, but without the use of $watch or $broadcast?

Updated fiddle thanks to selected answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/qqejytbz/4/

Comment: I'm sorry you missed my explanation in my post: "This JavaScript works as we are passing an object back from the service rather than a value. When a JavaScript object is returned from a service, Angular adds watches to all of its properties." You may also note that your problem was the same as the first person who commented. I'm glad you have resolved your issue. Please let me know if I can help further.

Comment: Yeah. I missed their comment initially.  Thanks for the response Zymotik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second controller, you're storing the value of `count` directly, which makes a copy of count at the time it was assigned. If count were an object, then `{{service.count}}` and `$scope.count` would just be a reference to the same object. Then modified properties of the object would be synchronized between controllers.

Eg.

```
//in DemoService
self.count = {value: 0};
// Binding in html for controller 1
{{service.count.value}}
// Assignment in controller 2:
$scope.count = DemoService.count;
//$scope.count.value === controller1.service.count.value === 0

service.count.value += 100
//$scope.count.value === controller1.service.count.value === 100
```

Note that Angular may not pick up on the changes to the object until the next full digest cycle.

Comment: When assigning an object to the vm/$scope Angular adds watches to all of its properties when it is binded to pick up any changes to those values.