# Updating controller during $http progress in angular factory

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular 1.5.7 I am using the `uploadEventHandlers` to get progress. It works in the factory but the values don't update in the controller.

Factory:

```
.factory("PostFactory", function($http,baseUrl) {
  var service = {};
  service.progressBar = 0;
  service.progressCounter = 0;

  service.createPost = function(payload) {

    return $http({
      data: payload,
      url: baseUrl + 'api/post',
      method: 'POST',
      uploadEventHandlers: {
        progress: function (e) {
          if (e.lengthComputable) {
            service.progressBar = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            service.progressCounter = service.progressBar;

            console.error("Inside factory: " + service.progressCounter);
          }
        }
      }
    }).then(function(response){ 
      return response.data;
    });

  return service;
  });
}
```

Controller:

```
   .controller('SendPostCtrl', function($scope,$timeout,PostFactory) {
      var post = { 
     // all my data (including a base64 encoded image)  to send to the server 
      }
      $scope.uploadProgress = PostFactory.progressCounter;
      $scope.$watch($scope.uploadProgress, function() {
        console.error("Inside controller: " + $scope.uploadProgress);
      });

      var promise = PostFactory.createPost(post);

      promise.then(function(response) {
       //do stuff after the server response with success data
      });
    });
```

As shown, the console will is:

```
> Inside controller: 0
> Inside factory: 13.1
> Inside factory: 26.3
> Inside factory: 39.4
> Inside factory: 52.6
> Inside factory: 65.8
> Inside factory: 78.9
> Inside factory: 92.1
> Inside factory: 100
```

How do I get realtime updates on the progress within the controller?

Comment: Where is PostFactory.createPost method declared?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Question updated to show `.createPost()`

Comment: I did get the controller updated using the $rootScope.$broadcast method suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables), but the counter gets to 100% well before the data transfer is complete, so maybe there's an issue with `uploadEventHandlers: { progress: }`

Comment: All `progress` does is break the data into chunks of 32768 and then report the percentage of 32768/total bytes, but does it within 1 second (0-100%) well before the data transfer is complete. What good doe this do anybody?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are expecting that the scope value *uploadProgress* is referring to the value of *progressCounter* in the service.
This is not the case as the value of *progressCounter* is a number, primitive type, and not a reference type which makes this line

```
$scope.uploadProgress = PostFactory.progressCounter;
```

only setting the value of *uploadProgress* to zero. Then when you are changing the *progressCounter* in the service this change is not reflected back to the *uploadProgress*. This will result in that the $watch is never triggered.

One solution is to watch the service variable instead of the scope variable

```
$scope.$watch('PostFactory.progressCounter', function() {
    $scope.uploadProgress = PostFactory.progressCounter;
    console.error("Inside controller: " + $scope.uploadProgress);
});
```

Comment: This method didn't not work, either - the controller is not updated.