# AngularJS Sending event to another controller ($broadcast, $window.localStorage, etc.)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I want to send an event to another controller.
To do this, I already know way using `$rootScope.$broadcast` or `$scope.$emit` then listen event using `$scope.$on`.

It is a general way, but my project initiates the controller in a different JS file.

```
//In broadcaster.js
function broadcasterCtrl(~~~~~, broadcasterService){
~~~~~~~~~~
}
function broadcasterService(~~~~~){
~~~~~~~~~~
}
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('broadcasterService', broadcasterService)
    .controller('broadcasterCtrl', broadcasterCtrl);

//In listener.js
function listenerCtrl(~~~~~, listenerService){
~~~~~~~~~~
}
function listenerService(~~~~~){
~~~~~~~~~~
}
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('listenerService', listenerService)
    .controller('listenerCtrl', listenerCtrl);
```

Because of this structure, the listener controller is initiated when the view(state) is called. So I used `$window.localStorage.setItem('key', value)`, but I don't like it because, I think, it is very vulnerable.

Is there any idea using `$broadcast`? or is it secure using localStorage?

Comment: You can use observer pattern to notify other controller see E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576798/angularjs-how-to-watch-service-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to share information across multiple controllers are services since services are singletons it's easier to manage and isolate a scope/variables for that purpose.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.factory('datepickerinfo', function() {
        var keyValue;

        datepickerinfo.setKey = function(key) {
            keyValue = key;
        };
        datepickerinfo.getKey = function(){
        return keyValue;
    }

    return datepickerinfo;
});
```

And Inject it:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, datepickerinfo) {
    $scope.dateKey = datepickerinfo.getKey();
}
```

**LocalStorage:**

You can use local storage too. If you don't have any important data. (Important data means don't share user crucial information using local storage.) Otherwise, local storage is a good way. But, keep in mind you should handle local storage properly whenever any updation or deletion occurs.

Comment: Agreed with Service option, that's what services are meant for.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing idea :)