# How to access filtered array of objects between two web pages in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to access filtered array of objects shown on current page on next page on selection of an item on current page.

### app.js

```
var App = angular.module('App', 
    ['ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'customFilters', 'pager', 
    'pagerDirective']);

App
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl:"./home.tpl.html"
    })
    .state('List', {
        url: '/List',
        templateUrl: './views/card-ui/list-card.html',
        // templateUrl: '/views/list.html',
        controller: 'ListController'
    })
    .state('Details', {
        url: '/Details',
        params: {padaIndex: null},
        templateUrl: './views/card-ui/details-card.html',
        // templateUrl: '/views/details.html',
        controller: 'DetailsController'
    })
});
```

### Controllers.js

```
App
.controller('ListController', function($scope, $state, PagerService) {
// .controller('ListController', function($scope, $state) {

    // Private Data
    var selectedCategory = null;
    /**** New Addition ****/
    var selectedAuthor = null;
    /**** End New Addition ****/

    // Model Data
    $scope.orderPada = '';

    // Assigns user selected Category to private variable selectedCategory
    $scope.selectCategory = function(newCategory) {
        selectedCategory = newCategory;
    }

    // Filter padas by selected Category
    $scope.categoryFilterFn = function(pada) {
        return selectedCategory == null || 
            pada.category == selectedCategory;
    }

    /**** New Addition ****/
    // Assigns user selected Author to private variable selectedAuthor
    $scope.selectAuthor = function(newAuthor) {
        selectedAuthor = newAuthor;
    }

    // Filter padas by selected Author
    $scope.authorFilterFn = function(pada) {
        return selectedAuthor == null || 
            pada.author == selectedAuthor;
    }
    /**** End of new addition ****/

    /***
     * Navigate to padadetails
     */
    $scope.navigatePadaDetails = function(url, params) {
        $state.go(url, params);
    }
});
```

```
App
.controller("DetailsController", function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $filter) {
    var counter = Number($stateParams.padaIndex);

    $scope.whichPada = Number($stateParams.padaIndex);
    $scope.oPada = $scope.data.padas[$scope.whichPada];
    $scope.padaCat = '';
    $scope.padaAuthor = '';
    $scope.padaQry = '';
    $scope.orderPada = '';
    $scope.direction = '';

    // Filter & sort
    $scope.filteredPadas = $filter('filter')($scope.data.padas, 
        $scope.padaCat); 
    $scope.filteredPadas = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredPadas, 
        $scope.padaAuthor); 
    $scope.filteredPadas = $filter('filter')($scope.filteredPadas, 
        $scope.padaQry); 
    $scope.filteredPadas = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredPadas, 
        $scope.orderPada, $scope.direction);

    // Swipe gestures
    // Material code
    $scope.onSwipeLeftPadaDetails = function(ev, target) {
        // alert('You swiped left!!');

        // Goto next pada
        $scope.navigateNextPada('PadaDetails', {padaIndex: counter});
    };

    $scope.onSwipeRightPadaDetails = function(ev, target) {
        // alert('You swiped right!!');

        // Goto previous pada
        $scope.navigatePrevPada('PadaDetails', {padaIndex: counter});

    };


    /***
     * Skips a pada to previous or next
     */
    $scope.skipPada = function(padaId, nSkip) {
        var newPadaIndex = null;

        // if (padaId && nSkip) {
        if ($scope.skipPada.arguments.length == 2) {
            // make padaId 0 based
            // padaId = padaId - 1;

            // Previous
            if (nSkip < 0) {
                // Add nSkip since it has signed value(-1)
                if (padaId + nSkip < 0) {
                    // numberOfPadas = data.padas.length-1
                    newPadaIndex = $scope.numberOfPadas;
                } else {
                    newPadaIndex = padaId + nSkip;
                }
            }

            // Next
            if (nSkip > 0) {
                // numberOfPadas = data.padas.length-1
                if (padaId + nSkip > $scope.numberOfPadas) {
                    newPadaIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    newPadaIndex = padaId + nSkip;
                }
            }
        }
        return newPadaIndex;
    };

    /***
     * Navigate to previous pada
     */
    $scope.navigatePrevPada = function(url, params) {
        var prevPada;

        prevPada = $scope.skipPada(params.padaIndex, -1);
        params.padaIndex = prevPada;
        $state.go(url, params);
    };

    /***`enter code here`
     * Navigate to next pada
     */
    $scope.navigateNextPada = function(url, params) {
        var nextPada;

        nextPada = $scope.skipPada(params.padaIndex, 1);
        params.padaIndex = nextPada;
        $state.go(url, params);
    };

});
```

### List.html

```
<md-content flex>
    <!-- Search/Filter Card -->
    <md-card md-theme="{{ appDefaults.showDarkTh`enter code here`eme ? 'dark-blue' : 
    appDefaults.theme || 'default' }}">
        <md-card-header layout ng-click="showSearch=!showSearch">
            <md-card-avatar class="md-user-avatar">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="img/material/baseline-search-24px.svg"> 
                </md-icon>
            </md-card-avatar>
            <md-card-header-text>
                <div class="md-headline">खोजें</div>
                <div class="md-subhead">क्रमबद्ध करें</div>
            </md-card-header-text>
        </md-card-header>

        <!-- Card contents -->
        <div ng-show="showSearch">
            <md-card-content>

                <label arial-label="category">पद श्रेणी चुनें</label>
                <md-select ng-model="catgry" ng- 
                change="selectCategory(catgry)">
                    <md-option value="">सभी श्रेणी</md-option>
                    <md-option value={{catgry}} 
                        ng-repeat="catgry in data.padas | orderBy:'category' | 
                        unique: 'category'">
                        {{catgry}}
                    </md-option>
                </md-select>

                <label aria-label="author">पद रचयिता चुनें</label>
                <md-select ng-model="authr" ng- 
                       change="selectCategory(authr)">
                    <md-option value="">सभी रचयिता</md-option>
                    <md-option value={{authr}} 
                        ng-repeat="authr in data.padas | orderBy:'author' | 
                        unique: 'author'">
                        {{authr}}
                    </md-option>
                </md-select>

                <md-input-container>
                    <label aria-label="pada search">पदों में खोजें</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="padaQry" />   
                </md-input-container>

                <md-radio-group ng-model="direction">
                    <md-radio-button value="" aria-label="आरोही क्रम">आरोही 
                        क्रम
                    </md-radio-button>    
                    <md-radio-button value="reverse" aria-label="अवरोही 
                        क्रम">अवरोही क्रम
                    </md-radio-button>
                </md-radio-group>
            </md-card-content>
        </div>
    </md-card>

    <div>
    <md-card  ng-repeat="pada in (filteredPadas = (data.padas | 
    filter:categoryFilterFn | filter:authorFilterFn | filter:padaQry | 
    orderBy:orderPada:direction))" 
    ng-click="navigatePadaDetails('PadaDetails', {padaIndex: pada.padaID- 
           1})">
        <md-card-header>
            <md-card-header-text>
                <span class="md-title">
                    {{pada.padaSankhya}}
                </span>
                <span class="md-subhead">
                    पृष्ठ: (ट. {{pada.pageNo}})/(गो. {{pada.gorelalPg}})
                </span>
            </md-card-header-text>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <p class="md-subhead">{{pada.author}} कौ पद:</p>
                <p class="md-headline">{{pada.title}}</p>
                <p class="md-subhead">श्रेणी - {{pada.category}}</p>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-content>
        <!-- <md-card-actions></md-card-actions> -->
        <md-footer layout layout-padding="">
            <span flex layout-align="start start">
                {{pada.lyrics.length}} पंक्तियाँ
            </span>
            <span flex layout-align="end start">
                {{$index + 1}}/{{filteredPadas.length}}
            </span>
        </md-footer>
    </md-card>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

### Deatails.html

```
 <md-content>
     <md-card 
     md-swipe-left="onSwipeLeftPadaDetails($event, $target)"
     md-swipe-right="onSwipeRightPadaDetails($event, $target)">
     <!-- md-swipe-up="onSwipeUpPadaDetails($event, $target)" -->
     <!-- md-swipe-down="onSwipeDownPadaDetails($event, $target)"> -->
         <md-card-header>
             <md-card-avatar>
                <img ng- 
                   src="img/material/ic_lightbulb_outline_black_48px.svg" 
                alt="light-bulb">
             </md-card-avatar>

             <md-card-header-text>
                <span class="md-title">{{oPada.padaSankhya}}</span>
                <span class="md-subhead">पृष्ठ: (ट. {{oPada.pageNo}}) / (गो. 
                {{oPada.gorelalPg}})</span>
             </md-card-header-text>
         </md-card-header>

         <md-card-title-text layout-padding>
             <span class="md-headline">{{oPada.title}}</span> <br>
             <span class="md-subhead">श्रेणी - {{oPada.category}}</span> <br>
             <span class="md-subhead">{{oPada.lyrics.length}} पंक्तियाँ</span>
         </md-card-title-text>

         <md-card-content>
                <p class="bandish">
                    <span class="author">
                        {{oPada.author ? data.padas[whichPada].author + " कौ 
                        पद" : ""}} 
                    </span>
                    <span class="raag">
                        {{oPada.raag ? ", राग-" + data.padas[whichPada].raag 
                            : 
                        ""}}
                    </span>
                    <span class="taal">
                        {{oPada.taal ? ", ताल-" + data.padas[whichPada].taal 
                            : 
                        ""}}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        {{oPada.tune ? ", धुनि-" + data.padas[whichPada].tune 
                            : 
                        ""}}
                    </span>
                </p>

                <div class="padaBody">

            <p class="padaLyrics" ng-repeat="line in oPada.lyrics 
                    track by $index">
                        {{line}}
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <span>{{oPada.note}}</span>
                    </p>

                </div>
         </md-card-content>
</md-content>
```

### filters.js

```
angular.module("customFilters", [])
// app
.filter("unique", function() {
    return function(data, propertyName) {
        if (angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyName)) {
            var results = [];
            var keys = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var val = data[i][propertyName];
                if (angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
                    keys[val] = true;
                    results.push(val);
                }
            }
            return results;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
})
```

### MainController.js

```
App
.constant("padaUrl", "data/pada.json")
.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope, $http, padaUrl) {

    // Data models
    $scope.data = {};

    // Read pada data
    $http.get(padaUrl)
        .then(function(response) {
            // Copy and remove first object
            $scope.data.pada0 = response.data.shift();
            // Copy pada.json array into model
            $scope.data.padas = response.data;
            $scope.numberOfPadas = $scope.data.padas.length - 1;
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.data.error = response;
    });
});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head></head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

   <div ng-cloak ng-show="data.error">
     Application data not loaded, <a ui-sref="index.html">click here to try again.</a>
   </div>

    <div ui-view ng-hide="data.error">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Say, I got filtered array of objects for "cat3" on Web Page 1 as as list of links. When I select a link from filtered list, I show details of selected item on Web Page 2. I want to iterate details of each item of filtered array of objects one by one using previous and next buttons or left right swiping gestures.

Comment: Use an angular service to share data across various parts of your app

Comment: Mya be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374003/angularjs-sending-event-to-another-controller-broadcast-window-localstorage/51374174#51374174