# Javascript: Self and This

Tags: javascript, prototype, this, self

Can anyone explain why do I get different values of self and this? Where self is a reference to this.

```
function Parent(){
   var self = this;
   this.func = function(){
      // self.a is undefined
      // this.a is 'Test'
      console.log(self.a, this.a);
   }
}

function Child(x){
   this.a = x;
}

Child.prototype.__proto__ = new Parent;
var ch = new Child('Test');
ch.func();
```

I've been using self on project and it's my first time to have this issue.

Comment: self and this are no longer referring to the same object. The following link may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this

Comment: ô the joy of javascript call context !

Comment: In `func`, it seems like `self` points to the `Parent`, but `this` points to the `Child`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This is why I like javascript, very different. Now I need to be more careful on nested callbacks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `self` refers to an instance of `Parent`, but only instances of `Child` have an `a` property.

```
function Parent(){
   var self = this; // this is an instance of Parent
   this.func = function(){
      console.log(self.a, this.a);
   }
}

function Child(x){
    this.a = x; // Instances of Child have an `a` property
}

Child.prototype.__proto__ = new Parent;
var ch = new Child('Test');

ch.func(); // Method called in context of instance of Child
```

So when you call `func` on an instance of `Child`, `this` refers to that instance. That's why `this.a` gives you the correct value inside `func`.

Answer (score 1):

Within `func`, `this` refers to an instance of `Child`.

```
Child.prototype.__proto__ = new Parent;
```

The prototype of `Child` is set to an instance of `Parent`. So when `ch.func()` is invoked, `func()` is on the prototype chain of `Child`, but is invoked in the context of `ch` which is an instance of `Child`

`self` is still referring to the instance of `Parent` which does not have an attribute `a`

To further illustrate:

```
var p = new Parent();

// this.a is undefined because this is an instance of Parent
p.func(); // undefined undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar",
    func: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log("outer func1:  this.foo = " + this.foo); //bar
        console.log("outer func2:  self.foo = " + self.foo); //bar
        (function() {
            console.log("inner func3:  this.foo = " + this.foo); //undefind
            console.log("inner func4:  self.foo = " + self.foo);//bar
        }());
    }
};
myObject.func();
```

Comment: In the inner function, though, this no longer refers to myObject. As a result, this.foo is undefined in the inner function, whereas the reference to the local variable self remains in scope and is accessible there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Foo() {
  this.bar = 'bar';
  return this;
}
Foo.prototype.test = function(){return 1;}



function Bar() {
  this.bro = 'bro';
  return this;
}
Bar.prototype.test2 = function(){return 2;}

function Cool2() {
  Foo.call(this);
  Bar.call(this);

  return this;
}
//console.log(Object.create(Bar.prototype));
var combine = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
//console.log(combine);

$.extend(combine, Object.create(Bar.prototype));
$.extend(combine, Object.create(Foo.prototype));

Cool2.prototype = Object.create(combine);
//Cool2.prototype.constructor = Cool2;

var cool = new Cool2();
 

console.log(cool.test()); // 1
console.log(cool.test2()); //2
console.log(cool.brow) //bro
console.log(cool.bar) //bar
console.log(cool instanceof Foo); //true
console.log(cool instanceof Bar); //false
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer