# knockout does not set an initial true value on radio button

Tags: knockout.js

The 1-way binding for the names + checkbox works fine, but it does not work initially for the radio button employeeTypeA although its value is true in the viewmodel the html shows the radio button as not set, why is that?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function()
        {
            var PersonViewModel = function()
            {
                this.firstName = ko.observable('Lisa');
                this.lastName = ko.observable('T');
                this.isCustomer = ko.observable(true);
                this.employeeTypeA = ko.observable(true);
                this.employeeTypeB = ko.observable(false);
            };

            var personViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(personViewModel, $('data').get(0));
        });
    </script>

    <div id="data">
        <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isCustomer" title="Is a customer" />
        <input name="x" type="radio" data-bind="checked: employeeTypeA" title="Employee type A" />
        <input name="x" type="radio" data-bind="checked: employeeTypeB" title="Employee type B" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `checked` binding works differently for radio buttons, from the documentation:

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s `value` attribute.

So you need to change your `PersonViewModel` to something like this:

```
var PersonViewModel = function()
{
    this.firstName = ko.observable('Lisa');
    this.lastName = ko.observable('T');
    this.isCustomer = ko.observable(true);
    this.employeeType = ko.observable('TypeB');                
};
```

And your radio buttons:

```
<input name="x" type="radio" data-bind="checked: employeeType" 
       value="TypeA" title="Employee type A" />
<input name="x" type="radio" data-bind="checked: employeeType" 
       value="TypeB" title="Employee type B" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xKcQs/)

If you want to keep the `employeeTypeA` and `employeeTypeB` properties you can introduce a computed property which returns the type:

```
this.employeeTypeA = ko.observable(false);
this.employeeTypeB = ko.observable(true);
this.employeeType = ko.computed(function()
{
     if (this.employeeTypeA())
        return 'TypeA';
     if (this.employeeTypeB())
        return 'TypeB';
},this);
```

Also in this case you need to add the `value` attributes on your radio buttons.

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uugjH/)

Comment: I checked the knockoutJS site and looked at the tutorial:        wantsSpam: ko.observable(true), but I did not see that wantsSpam is bound to a visibility property... not the radio button directly.
As you also know about ASP.NET MVC would it not be a better idea to consider this Boolean to String 'Converter' in the server side viewmodel whatever that looks like?!

Comment: When I put your last code block into my visual studio html file I get 2 errors/warnings: suspicious use this operator and not all code path return a value.

Comment: Another question I have is why do you have the made this: "this.employeeTypeA()" and not "this.employeeTypeA". As far my javascript beginner knowledge goes employeeType is a property BUT you invoke like a function? This is no critic just a curious question :)

Comment: To answer your questions: 1. How to wire this with ASP.NET MVC is completely different question, you should ask it in separete question. 2. Regarding the warnings: a `return ''` is missing at the end of computed. suspicious use `this`: it will work in this case but there are multiple ways to handle it like introducing a [`self` local reference to `this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/) etc. 3. Regarding the "this.employeeTypeA()" call: `ko.observable` returns a function so `employeeTypeA` is a function and you need to call it with  "this.employeeTypeA()" to get its value.

Comment: ok thanks sounds good. I have seen samples using var self = this; Seems people are really using it differently browsing google. About 3.) It works also without the () ... :P 1.) ok will do a new question.

Comment: Great... thanks for deciphering the docs for me :) I read it, guess I read it too fast.