# What difference between This and That

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know and understand the different between this and that, and when I have to use it.
I ready many post and many tutorial but I don't understand yet

this is my class

```
function Container(param) {

    function dec() {
        if (secret > 0) {
            secret -= 1;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    this.member = param;
    var secret = 3;
    var that = this;

    this.service = function () {
        console.log(this.member); // foo
        console.log(that.member); // foo
        return dec() ? that.member : null;
    };
}
```

New

```
var myContainer = new Container('foo');
myContainer.service()
```

Calling `myContainer.service()` will return 'abc' the first three times it is called. 
After that, it will return null

Why i have to do `var that = this` ??

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: Have you tried it without `that` to see what happens? Might be a good way to learn about what's going on.

Comment: I dont see the need of `that` in your example. Try `var s = myContainer.service; s()` and see what happens with/without `that`.

Comment: @CoderDennis yes and it works

Comment: Similar questions - [self=this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this) and [difference between self and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875767/difference-between-this-and-self-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

`this` is a variable that gets the context of the current function (which depends on how it was called).

`that` has no special meaning. It is just a variable to which a value has been assigned.

In this particular case, `that` is assigned the value that `this` has while the `Container` is running, and is used inside the `service` function (but still has the value that is the context of the call to `Container`. Since `service` is a different function, its value of `this` could be different.

---

*Normally*, for this particular design of function, `Container` would be called as a constructor function (so `this` would be the instance object of `Container`) and then `service` would be called in the context of that instance object so you could use `this` instead of passing the value around via `that`. I have no idea why the author of that code chose to use `that` here.

Comment: but why i have to do var that = this; ? http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: @monkeyUser: you don't *have to*. If you don't want - you may not define `that` variable.

Comment: @monkeyUser — Otherwise `that` wouldn't have a value at all.

Comment: have you got a clear example?