# Javascript: each element of a array of objects having same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I created a 2D array that contains an object, and each object has two variables.

When I printed out those objects, I found that every object has the same value.

If I change one of the objects, other objects will change too.

```js
class test{
    constructor(x, y){
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(self.x, self.y);
    }
}

arr = new Array(3);

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr[i] = new Array(3);
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j] = new test(i, j);
    }
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j].print();
    }
}
```

It just prints nine 2 2.
I have no idea what's going on.

Even if I tried:

```
arr[1][2] = new test(2, 3);
```

It prints nine 2 3.

I will be appreciated if anyone helps me.

:P

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `self.x` to be `this.x`, etc. unless this is really a Python question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `self` you use is [actually the `window` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875767/difference-between-this-and-self-in-javascript), so `self.x = x` just attaches an `x` property to `window` and sets the value. When you call `console.log(self.x, self.y);` this gets the `x` and `y` properties from `window` and since there is only a single instance of that, you get the last assigned values.

```js
class test{
    constructor(x, y){
        self.x = x;
        self.y = y;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(self.x, self.y);
    }
}

new test(4, 2);

console.log(window.x);
console.log(window.y);
```

You want to use `this` to refer to the current object instance

```js
class test{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(this.x, this.y);
    }
}

arr = new Array(3);

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr[i] = new Array(3);
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j] = new test(i, j);
    }
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j].print();
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG I didn't notice that.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ben_TW it's alright, we all make mistakes. And learn from them. The reason I know about `self` is because I've made a mistake very similar to yours in the past. It also took me a while to solve :P

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript is not Python, use `this`, and it will work.

```js
class test{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(this.x, this.y);
    }
}

arr = new Array(3);

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr[i] = new Array(3);
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j] = new test(i, j);
    }
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j].print();
    }
}
```

(You luckily/unluckily ended up using [`Window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self), everywhere)

Comment: @Teemu, thanks. It disturbed me a little, since it should have been complaining about accessing a field of `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

The assignment of `x` and `y` to `self` in the constructor is your problem, change `self` to `this` to point to the current instance of the class object.

```js
class test{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(this.x, this.y);
    }
}

arr = new Array(3);

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr[i] = new Array(3);
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j] = new test(i, j);
    }
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j].print();
    }
}
```

From the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self):

> The Window.self read-only property returns the window itself, as a
>   WindowProxy. It can be used with dot notation on a window object (that
>   is, window.self) or standalone (**self**)

So in your case when you assigned `x` and `y` to `self.x` and `self.y` two new properties of the `self` was created and you kept overwriting them in your loop which resulted in the last value (2,2) of the iteration being assigned to the `x` and `y` property of `self`

Answer (score 2):

The `self` doesnot refer to the instance of `class`. `self` in another name for `window`. See the snippet what is `self`

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self)

> The `Window.self` read-only property **returns the window itself**

```js
class test{
    constructor(x, y){
        console.log(self === window) //true
        console.log(self) //widnow object       
    }
}
let x = new test(1,2);
```

So every time you create a new instance of `test` `self.x` and `self.y` is change. `self.y` and `self.x` is same a `window.x` and `window.y`

Using `this` in place of `self` will solve the problem.

```js
class test{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    print(){
        console.log(this.x, this.y);
    }
}

arr = new Array(3);

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    arr[i] = new Array(3);
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j] = new test(i, j);
    }
}

for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
        arr[i][j].print();
    }
}
```