# How to call element itself from inline javascript in attribute? Remove attribute in particular

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

This works

```html
<body onload="document.body.classList.add('loaded'); document.body.removeAttribute('onload')">
```

and it's not a problem for this particular case, but I need the same fuctionality on multiple elements and I hope there's a solution without giving all of them an `id` attribute.

I tried

```html
<body onload="this.classList.add('loaded'); this.removeAttribute('onload')">
```

and

```html
<body onload="self.classList.add('loaded'); self.removeAttribute('onload')">
```

but (obviously to some) it doesn't work.

How do I get the element in which JavaScript is called from attributes like `onload`, `onclick`, etc.?

Elaborating my use-case:
All of my styles, except `critical.css` are loading with a non-blocking hack like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700%7CPT+Sans+Narrow%7CSource+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900&amp;subset=all&amp;display=swap" type="text/css">
```

I don't like that the `onload="if(media!='all')media='all'"` part is still visible in DevTools after everything is loaded properly. I also don't completely understand how to do this in a better way. It would be interesting to find out the answer to my exact question, but I would also much appreciate an answer that offers the best approach. My stack is HTML5, CSS, vanilla JavaScript, PHP 7.2. No frameworks at the moment (not counting Bootstrap).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between this and self in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875767/difference-between-this-and-self-in-javascript)

Comment: better to use DOMContentLoaded event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: @MisterJojo Elaborated a bit. See question. I don't exactly see how to use `DOMContentLoaded` and difference between `this` and `self` isn't too helpful since neither of them work.

Comment: I just think you have to do do all this JS code in a script part, not in head or body part