# Is there any JS built-in class method run only once when any method is referred?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, built-in

I have a class for reloading some elements.

```
const getMe = async () => await 
  fetchURL("https://MY.SITE/api/users/me")
    .then((res) => res.data);

class loader {
  EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED() {
    self.ME = (async () => await getMe())();
  }
  me() {
    $("#me").html(`${self.ME.grade}${self.ME.number}[Tickets: ${self.ME.likeTicket}]`);
  } // ** likeTicket depends on ME **
  async chart() {
    if ($("body").find("#chart").length) {
      const musicChart = await fetchURL(`https://MY.SITE/api/music/chart?&gender=${self.ME.gender}`);
      $("#chart").html(await listElementsOf(musicChart.data.list));
    } // ** listElementsOf depends on ME ( It lets me know what musics I 'liked' to ) **
  }
  async search(q) {
    if ($("body").find("#searchResult").length){
      if(q) $("#searchResult").attr("data-q", q);
      else q = $("#searchResult").attr("data-q");

      const searchResult = await fetchURL(`https://MY.SITE/api/music/search?q=${q}`);
      $("#searchResult").html(await listElementsOf(searchResult));
    }
  }
  meAndChart() {
    self.me();
    self.chart();
  }
  loadEverything() {
    self.meAndChart();
    self.search();
  }
}
```

I need to reload ME before reloading any other element, and I'm seeking a way to do this. I can employ `new` like `new loader.me();`, but I don't want to use `new` every time.

Is there any way for the intended job? Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the *other elements* are (DOM elements?). And how would you reload them? Why do you want to reload `ME` if it is not even used in you class? I can't make much sense of your code.

Comment: @GOTO0 Actually other methods use ME, but for security(?) I covered it. `elements` are DOM elements as you said, and I need to use ME, private user detail, to reload 'me' and 'chart' elements. I reload them by re-fetching data from the target site.
ex) `const musicChart = await fetchURL(\`https://MY.SITE/api/music/chart?gender=${self.ME.gender}\`;` `$("#chart").html(await listElementsOf(musicChart.data.list));` - I used JQuery.

Comment: I would put the `fetchURL` calls into a central function and use only that function to fetch data. Then, in that function, you could load `ME` only if necessary.

Comment: @GOTO0 I don't get what you mean by 'central function'. I edited my question so that you can understand the overall structure, so please let me know how to make it. Thanks

Comment: So, the methods in your code where `ME` is being referenced are `me` and `chart`, right? And you want to run `EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED` before any of those two?

Comment: @GOTO0 You're right, but I don't want them to load ME double time when I called `loader.meAndChart()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well a typical approach would be creating internal methods for `me` and `chart` that run without reloading `ME`, and public methods that call `EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED` before doing so. `meAndChar` would call `EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED` first, and then the internal methods.

Comment: @GOTO0 Appreciate your tip. I will implement that way.

Comment: I've added an answer to show the code in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code:

- change `EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED` so that `ME` is set to the awaited object rather than a promise.
- Using `this` instead of `self` for the current object (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875767/difference-between-this-and-self-in-javascript) for details).
- Renamed `me` and `chart` to `_me` and `_chart` respectively.
- Added methods `me` and `chart` that call the internal methods after `EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED`.
- Updated `meAndChart` to call the internal methods after `EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED`.

Note that it is generally a good practice (and often necessary) to call `async` functions with `await`, and that requires the caller functions to be also `async`.

```js
const getMe = async () => await 
  fetchURL("https://MY.SITE/api/users/me")
    .then((res) => res.data);

class loader {
  async EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED() {
    this.ME = await getMe();
  }
  _me() {
    $("#me").html(`${this.ME.grade}${this.ME.number}[Tickets: ${self.ME.likeTicket}]`);
  } // ** likeTicket depends on ME **
  async _chart() {
    if ($("body").find("#chart").length) {
      const musicChart = await fetchURL(`https://MY.SITE/api/music/chart?&gender=${self.ME.gender}`);
      $("#chart").html(await listElementsOf(musicChart.data.list));
    } // ** listElementsOf depends on ME ( It lets me know what musics I 'liked' to ) **
  }
  async me() {
    await this.EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED();
    this._me();
  }
  async chart() {
    await this.EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED();
    await this._chart();
  }
  async search(q) {
    if ($("body").find("#searchResult").length){
      if(q) $("#searchResult").attr("data-q", q);
      else q = $("#searchResult").attr("data-q");

      const searchResult = await fetchURL(`https://MY.SITE/api/music/search?q=${q}`);
      $("#searchResult").html(await listElementsOf(searchResult));
    }
  }
  async meAndChart() {
    await this.EVERYonceWHENmethodCALLED();
    this._me();
    await this._chart();
  }
  async loadEverything() {
    await this.meAndChart();
    await this.search();
  }
}
```