# Javascript (prototype) method call from ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written some object oriented Javascript like this:

```
function MyClass(){

    this.SomeFunc(arg1){
        result = <some processing on arg1>;
        return result;
    };

    this.SomeOtherFunc(){
        return $.ajax({
            <some restful call>
        }).done(function(){
            var localvar = this.SomeFunc(<value obtained by restful call>);
            <some operations with localvar>;
        });
    };
};

var myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.SomeOtherFunc();
```

And I get an error in the web console: "this.SomeFunc is not a function". If I call it within a function directly, there is no problem. The call fails only inside Ajax. What would be the proper way of making this function call?

Comment: May want to use [`var self = this;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this) and make it easier on yourself. scope can be a different concept in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` in your callback function is different from the `this` referring to `SomeFunc`, try doing:

```
this.SomeOtherFunc(){
    var thatFunc = this; //get hold of this
    return $.ajax({
        <some restful call>
    }).done(function(){
        var localvar = thatFunc.SomeFunc(<value obtained by restful call>);
        <some operations with localvar>;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you can also make sure of the $.proxy(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method which allows you to pass in the context. For example, you could do

```
this.SomeOtherFunc(){
    return $.ajax({
        <some restful call>
    }).done($.proxy(function(){
        var localvar = thatFunc.SomeFunc(<value obtained by restful call>);
        <some operations with localvar>;
    }, this)); // Pass in what 'this' should be in method
};
```

Here, the callback function will execute with `this` referencing the object passed in as the second parameter.

```
$.proxy(function(){ 
    // do stuff here 
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of the primary function `MyClass` is your *constructor*.
This means you have to define the `SomeFunc` in there, but you are calling it.
That's the problem shown in you console.

You can fix it my *defining* the function there, instead of calling it:

```
function MyClass(){
  // ----------vvvvvvvvvvv was missing
  this.SomeFunc = function(arg1) {
    result = <some processing on arg1>;
    return result;
  };

  // ---------------vvvvvvvvvvv same here
  this.SomeOtherFunc = function() {
    var _this = this
    return $.ajax({
      <some restful call>
    }).done(function(){
      // ------------v use _this instead of _this
      var localvar = _this.SomeFunc(<value obtained by restful call>);
      <some operations with localvar>;
    });
  };
};

var myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.SomeOtherFunc();
```

Another way of defining the functions is via the prototype:

```
MyClass = function() { ... }
MyClass.prototype.SomeFunc = function(arg1) {
  return <some processing on arg1>
}
MyClass.prototype.SomeOtherFunc = function() {
  var _this = this
  return $.ajax({ ... }).done(function(data) {
    _this.SomeFunc(data)
  })
}
```

The main difference is, that creating functions in the *constructor* will create a new `function` for each call of `new MyClass`.

Hope that helps.