# Calling function inside javascript class

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I have the following javascript class (really don't know if it is the best solution) and I wan't to call a function that is definded in this class, insinde another function defined in the same class.

```
step1 = {
    init: function(){
        this.events();
    },

    events: function(){
        fct = this; // i stored this in a variable so that i don't lose it
        $(document).on('click', '.form-line li', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            fct.changeCategoryValue($(this));
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.alert-form .confirm', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.fancybox.close(true);
        });
    },

    changeCategoryValue: function(el) {
        cat = el.hasClass('has-sub') ? '' : el.data('id');
        title = el.hasClass('has-sub') ? '' : el.data('title');
        $('#cat-title').val(title);
        $("input[name='category']").val(cat);
    }
```

As you an see I wan't to call the changeCategoryValue function but if I call it with this.changeCategoryValue it won't work. Any suggestions on how to improve the code?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Is there an error, or are you requesting an optimization? `fct = this` and then later `function(){ fct.changeCategoryValue }` is typical.

Comment: You are right, there is not problem. That is why I asked for an improvement. I don't know, but it doesen't seem right (usual) the solution i implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you may change the scope of the function callback:

```
$(document).on('click', '.form-line li', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.changeCategoryValue($(e.currentTarget));
}.bind(this));
```

Use `.bind(this)` so the scope of `function(e){...}` will be the instance of `step1` instead of `$('.form-line li',document)`. Now, to still target the clicked/selected `.form-line li`, you can access the object via `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: @TudorRavoiu oops, I left out the most important detail! Answer updated.

Comment: Ok, this works now. I had to make a little modification in the changeCategoryValue function because it seems that $(e.target) is in fact the "a" element inside of "li" and not the clicked "form-line li"  element.

Comment: @TudorRavoiu in your case it might be `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target` - I always get them mixed up!

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
step1.changeCategoryValue($(this));
```

Comment: ok, this works, but is it also another solution? so that if  the classname will change than the calling won't change?

Answer (score 0):

you have added property to the class why don't you call it using class name like this :

```
step1.changeCategoryValue('any_element_ref');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a proper object. This even allows you call init in the constructor if you wan't.

```
function Step() { this.init(); }

Step.prototype.init = function() { this.events(); };

Step.prototype.events = function() {
    var self = this;
    $(document).on('click', '.form-line li', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self.changeCategoryValue($(this));
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.alert-form .confirm', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.fancybox.close(true);
    });
};

Step.prototype.changeCategoryValue = function(el) {
    cat = el.hasClass('has-sub') ? '' : el.data('id');
    title = el.hasClass('has-sub') ? '' : el.data('title');
    $('#cat-title').val(title);
    $("input[name='category']").val(cat);
};

var step1 = new Step();
```

Comment: Overall this is best, but still has the `self` variable which the OP doesn't want (`fct` in their implementation).

Comment: In case the OP is worried about using self it is quite a standard javascript pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this

Comment: I agree, per my comment on the question itself, but nevertheless OP would like to see alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

you can try use clojure like this:

```
step1 = (function(){
            function events(){
                $(document).on('click', '.form-line li', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    changeCategoryValue($(this));
                });

                $(document).on('click', '.alert-form .confirm', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.fancybox.close(true);
                });
            }
            function changeCategoryValue(el) {
                cat = el.hasClass('has-sub') ? '' : el.data('id');
                title = el.hasClass('has-sub') ? '' : el.data('title');
                $('#cat-title').val(title);
                $("input[name='category']").val(cat);
            }
            function init(){
                events();
            }

            return {
                init:init,
                changeCategoryValue: changeCategoryValue
            }
        })()
```