# Knockout.js - Multiple ViewModels do not work

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js and I want to have a Master ViewModel that contains multiple ViewModels. Then I want to print properties of the ViewModels to the user but I can not get it right. Please help.

JavaScript Code:

```
var aViewModel = function()
{
    self.test = "test from a";
};

var bViewModel = function()
{
    self.test = "test from b";
};

masterVM = {a: new aViewModel(),
            b: new bViewModel()};

ko.applyBindings(masterVM);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="test-div">
    <span data-bind="text: a.test"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: b.test"></span>
</div>
```

The fiddle address is:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZyK4x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any magical `self` keyword in JavaScript.

It is only a [common idiom which is used to maintain a reference to the `this`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this)

So you are missing the `var self = this;` from you view models:

```
var aViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.test = "test from a";
};

var bViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.test = "test from b";
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mEM3/).