# Adding model to a collection after save method in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am using the save method when my data is submitted. On success callback of the save method, the collection should be updated with the model which i have saved since i want to get the id of the model from my server. My code is as below

```
var app = app || {};
app.AllDoneView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#frmAddDone',

events:{
'click #addDone':'addDone'
},

addDone: function(e ) {
e.preventDefault();
var formData = {

        doneHeading: this.$("#doneHeading").val(),
        doneDescription: this.$("#doneDescription").val(),

        };
var donemodel = new app.Done();
   donemodel.save(formData,

   {
       success :function(data){

      /*my problem is here how do i listen to collection event add that has been
        instantiated in intialize property to call renderDone . My tried code is

        var donecollection = new app.AllDone();
        donecollection.add(donemodel);



        and my response from server is
       [{id:145, doneHeading:heading , doneDescription:description,                  

         submission_date:2014-08-27 03:20:12}]





       */

       }, 
       error: function(data){

           console.log('error');
       },

    });
   },
  initialize: function() {
  this.collection = new app.AllDone();
  this.collection.fetch({
          error: function () {
          console.log("error!!"); 
        },
        success: function (collection) {
        console.log("no error");

      }
   });
  this.listenTo( this.collection, 'add', this.renderDone );


 },

 renderDone: function( item ) {
    var doneView = new app.DoneView({
        model: item
    });

    this.$el.append( doneView.render().el );
 }
 });
```

Collection is

```
var app = app || {};
app.AllDone = Backbone.Collection.extend({
url: './api',
model: app.Done,

});
```

Model is

```
var app = app || {};
app.Done = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: "./insert_done",
});
```

View is

```
var app = app || {};
app.DoneView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: _.template( $( '#doneTemplate' ).html() ),

render: function() {
    function
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );
    return this;

    }
});
```

Comment: `this` in your `success` callback refers to the callback method itself, which apparently doesn't have any `this.collection` variable.

Comment: How do i add the model to my collection in success callback, also the same collection should be able to call the renderDone method because i need to update the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success callback you create an entirely new collection, which doesn't have any listeners registered. This is the reason why the `renderDone` isn't triggered.

The model you receive from the server should be added to the collection which is attached directly to your view, `this.collection`:

```
var self = this,
    donemodel = new app.Done();

donemodel.save(formData, {
    success :function(data){
        // this is the collection you created in initialize
        self.collection.add(donemodel);
    }, 
    error: function(data){
        console.log('error');
    }

});
```

Comment: you are awesome, and u helped me increase my knowledge. I am new to backbone. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: i will be highly thankful to you if u help me understand the significance of the line, var self = this,donemodel = new app.Done();

Comment: There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this