# Chrome Extension: Why Isn't It Working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the current URL of the tab in chrome and then initiate a request to a site and get content back and write it to document body. Here's my chrome ext. js:

```
var engine = {

    run: function () {
        chrome.tabs.query({
            'active': true,
            'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
        }, function (tabs) {
            var url = tabs[0].url;
            var urlfinal = 'http://SOMESITEHERE.com/api.php?url=' + url;
            var response = this.connect(urlfinal);
            document.write(response);
        });
    },



    //console.log(this.url),

    connect: function (link) {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", link, false);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }

};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    engine.run();
});
```

But this throws: Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: undefined is not a function ... bla bla

What I'm doing wrong? What is the best approach?

EDIT:

Here's My Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "SOMETHINGHERE",
  "description": "SOMETHINGHERE",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://SITEHERE.com/",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The best approach is to think, look at _"bla bla"_ and see what exactly is throwing this error. At a glance, I don't think `this` is what you this is.

Comment: Here it is: `Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.engine.run (chrome-extension://nleccpfdokiokcgnlfomgajdfcpclkja/popup.js:6:14)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://nleccpfdokiokcgnlfomgajdfcpclkja/popup.js:29:10) `

Comment: Would it not be down to the fact, your Function is actually not assigned? e.g. Function MyFunc() instead of Function()

Comment: Never ever use `document.write` in a callback... The document's DOM will completely be replaced if you do that.

Comment: @RobW I'm testing dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"TypeError: undefined is not a function" means that you're trying to call something that has the value `undefined` as if it was a function.

In your case, you call `this.connect(urlfinal)`, but `this` is not what you expect it to be (not `engine`).

You are **inside a callback, not your `run` function anymore**, and `this` has no property `connect`. Therefore, `this.connect == undefined`. In these circumstances, calling `this.connect()` throws that error.

To solve this, you can, for instance, store the top level `this` object, and let closures take care of the rest:

```
run: function () {
    var _this = this;
    chrome.tabs.query({
        'active': true,
        'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT
    }, function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        var urlfinal = 'http://SOMESITEHERE.com/api.php?url=' + url;
        var response = _this.connect(urlfinal);
        document.write(response);
    });
}
```

See more information on this technique [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this).

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns url variable as undefined. I've set my permissions as well in manifest. Question updated.

Comment: That would be a different question. I would first to `encodeURIComponent(url)` though.

Comment: Could you help? I'm screwed with this @Xan

Comment: No actually it is returning tabs[0].url as undefined.

Comment: Try `currentWindow: true` instead of passing an explicit constant. Also, did you properly reload the extension after the manifest change?

Comment: are you calling tabs from background script or content script?