# KnockoutJS: Function Scope Error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-viewmodel-plugin

This code is in a KnockoutJS viewmodel:

```
function myViewModel()
{
    this.prop1 = ko.observable(123);
    this.prop2 = ko.observable("Hello");
    ..
    ..
}

myViewModel.prototype.func1 = function()
    {
  alert(this.prop1());             //works fine here

        myTimer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            alert(this.prop1());   //this.prop1() raises an undefined error
        }, 3000);                  //from console: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  
};
```

Why is the property not recognized within the timer callback? Looks like a scope issue, but I can't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about [Javascript scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and [the `var self = this` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this). The `this` keyword can behave unexpectedly in callback functions, as it may be set to something unexpected (like the function calling the timeout callback, or `window`, or...).

Something like* this will be an immediate solution to your problem:

```
myViewModel.prototype.func1 = function()
{
    var self = this;
    alert(self.prop1());             //works fine here

    myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        alert(self.prop1());
    }, 3000);                
};
```

<sub>* "like" this, because your question does not have code to actually *reproduce* your problem; a repro would be much more useful in helping you solve a problem</sub>

Comment: Hello Jeroen, and thanks a million; that did it. You did advise me to read up on JavaScript scopes in another post, but regretfully, I did not. I never quite understood the self keyword. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped. Even if you don't have time to read up on it (it's a dense topic), just remember to always start your view model constructor functions with `var self = this;` and use `self` instead of `this` everywhere, and you'll be spared a whole slew of problems.

Comment: I'll be sure to do that. Thank you for the tip, and for the solution. You're a life saver, Jeroen.

Comment: @iSofia Just in the interests of education - the problem here is that a setTimeout call will always be in the context of window (meaning `Boolean(window === this)` evaluates to true). There are ways to fix this but since you are still fairly new to javascript I won't confuse you with them. You are better off using `var self = this` as @Jeroen suggested.

Comment: +1 @Samih, feel free to slipstream your comment into the answer.