# Why can I not access an array in factory while I am in a forEach loop with Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

I have the following question: Why is it impossible for me to access my array in a forEach loop with Angular. I have made this factory with an array and a function, within the function I have this forEach loop. Outside of the forEach loop I can acces my array with the `this` keyword. In the forEach loop it gives me a undefined value.

```
.factory("sendOrder", function () {


    return {
        paired: [],

        send: function () {
            var names = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var ordered = document.getElementsByClassName('ordered');
            var i = 0;
            console.log(this.paired);//I can access it from here


           angular.forEach(names, function (amount, key) {
            console.log(this.paired);//Unable to access

               i++; 
            return;
                })
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: [You Don't Know JS: this and Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes) is so good at teaching you why `this` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the context of the function changes - `this` is not what it originally was. The usual fix is to set the original context to a variably (usually called `self`):

```
.factory("sendOrder", function () {


    return {
        paired: [],

        send: function () {
                var self = this;
                var names = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                var ordered = document.getElementsByClassName('ordered');
                var i = 0;
                console.log(this.paired);//I can access it from here


               angular.forEach(names, function (amount, key) {
                console.log(self.paired);//should be fine now

                   i++; 
                return;
                    })
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Is there a way I can still use my array or should I just work around it?

Comment: Absolutely, sorry, posted my answer before it was done. Just assign this to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Just like regular oop in javascript.

Comment: By the way, the solution you posted did not work untill I moved `var self = this` within the function. Updated your solution. Still you got me on the right track! I think `this` in your solution did reference the factory object not the returned object.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help. [Angular lets you set the context](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) (this) in `forEach`. It's one of the arguments. You don't have to set any other variables:

`angular.forEach(obj, iterator, [context]);`

You've passed in `obj` and `iterator`. Just pass in something for `context` and that will be `this` in the function.

Comment: I see...Interesting. Did not know I was able to do that. Thanks

Comment: You can do the same thing in plain old JavaScript array `forEach` too.

Comment: Yes I know but I want to learn it the Angular way and sometimes Angular is really close to plain javascript.

Comment: It's in the documentation, so I don't think you have to worry about it not being the Angular way. Self is a JavaScript thing in general, looks like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this