# Unable to handle undefined collections in Knockout.js Observable Array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable array of items in which each item has a collection of images (example below):

```
{"itemImages":[{"id":4,"itemId":9,"itemImageUrl":"$_57.JPG","createdOn":"2015-02-25T21:41:38.193","modifiedOn":"2015-02-25T21:41:38.193"}],"id":9,"itemName":"Item 1","itemDescription":"Item 1","itemPrice":5.00,"itemQuantity":1,"itemInStock":1,"createdOn":"2015-02-25T21:41:38.193","modifiedOn":"2015-02-25T21:41:38.193"}
```

OR the below JSON when no image available:

```
{"itemImages":[],"id":9,"itemName":"Item 1","itemDescription":"Item 1","itemPrice":5.00,"itemQuantity":1,"itemInStock":1,"createdOn":"2015-02-25T21:41:38.193","modifiedOn":"2015-02-25T21:41:38.193"}
```

The issue I am having is that the Image collection is not always populated and in these instances, I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemImages' of undefined

I get that the error is saying the collection is undefined and have been trying to handle this by setting the image to a 'no-image' image in these cases. Even with this check, the error is still being thrown which implies I am writing the computed observable logic incorrectly.

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var ViewModel = function () {

                var self = this;

                self.items = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Model.ItemsJSON));
            };


        var vm = new ViewModel();

        // Iterates over each item.
        _.each(vm.items(), function (item) {

            var self = this;

            item.imageUrl = ko.computed(function () {
                if (item.itemImages[0].length == 0)
                { var fileName = 'no-image-jpg' }
                else { fileName = item.itemImage[0].itemImageUrl }

                var url = '@Model.ImageUrlPrefix' + fileName

                return url;
            });
        //End Foreach loop.
        });

        ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And then for the Html, I am iterating over the item observable array on the viewmodel.

```
<div id="list-container" class="row">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'list-template', foreach: items }"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="list-template">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl }"/>
            </div>
      ...
```

Would appreciate if anyone could point out why my computed observable is not catching undefined collections and setting the fileName to 'no-image.jpg' for them.

Comment: The problem is not directly apparent from what you've posted, you'd get better help with a short-as-possible repro.

Comment: As to the question, you assume that the collection is undefined, but the error says "property 'itemImages' ***of*** undefined". So it is probably `this.item` that's the culprit. Consider using [the `var self = this;` idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/q/962033/419956) (or see [a Knockout-specific suggestion in their docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this)).

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeroen pointed out, you are on the wrong track. It is not the `itemImages` property which is `undefined`. It fails to find a property **in an undefined object**!

Which means that you *think* you're accessing your view model, but you're actually referencing `undefined`.

You are probably accessing `this` incorrectly. You assume that it's the ViewModel, but it's something else. Please refer to [this section of the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this) for details on how to fix it.

In short: you need to create a variable that keeps the reference to `this` accross functions and `computed`s. For example:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have been playing around with this for a bit. If there is an image in the itemImages collection on the item, then no error is thrown and the image displays as wanted. It is just when the collection is empty. I will and amend the example to better give the context of what I have set up.