# backbone view getting "this" context in nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone view class, whose render() method calls a showCal() method (via a plug-in for example fullcalendar).

the showCal() method has an options hash, internally having several functions.  For example

```
showCal: function() {
...
$('#somediv').fullCalendar({

});
```

Inside the above code, there is another callback function, "eventDrop", which shows qtip.

```
...
fullCalendar({
   eventDrop: function() {
     $(someElement).qtip({
     ));
   }
});
```

And the qtip itself has a many html UI elements with event handler functions.  So the full hierarchy of nested scopes looks somewhat like this...

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  render: function() {
    this.showCal();
  },
  ...
  showCal: function() {
    ...
    $(element).fullCalendar({
      ...
      eventDrop: function() {
        $(someElement).qtip({
          ...
          events: {
            render: function() {
              $(button).on('click', function(e) {
                ... code to handle the event.
              });
            }
          }
        });
      },
      ...
    });
  }
});
```

In the above example (with its deep level of nested function scopes), I am writing a event handler for button click.  In this event handler, I have to access the backbone view **this** object, and from that *this* object, access the collection object and do a save on a model belonging to this collection.

A couple of direct approaches would be:
i)  Store the model object into the qtip element as a "data" attribute, and directly make an ajax call inside this nested fn.  But this would violate the MVC principle, and leads a hackish code.
ii) raise a custom event in this nested fn, and handle it at the view level directly, where the *this* would become available.

Are there any other [better] approaches to such situation?

Comment: The simplest approach would probably be to just save the context in the beginning of your event handler, for example `showCal: function () { var self = this;...` and then use that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this