# Marionette - using listenTo in a function or in an object

Tags: javascript, marionette

I'm trying to use something like this:

```
var a = Marionette.Object.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        //Works fine
        this.listenTo(this, "something", function(){...});

        //Problem
        (function(){
            this.listenTo(this, "somethingElse", function(){...});
        })();

        //Same...
        var b = function(){
            this.listenTo(this, "somethingElse", function(){...});
        }

        b();
    }
});
```

When I try to run this code, it says:

> Cannot read property 'listenTo' of undefined

for the functions. But the question is why?

As far as I know, the `initialization:` get's called, when everything is ready, that's why the other listener at the beginning works. If I put the listener into a function, it should be the same, because, when it gets called, the Object is already initialized so `this` is present.

Any idea how could I solve this with, leaving the listener inside the function?

Thanks in advance!

*Solution for the above (thanks to sp00m)*

**-- New question --**

Achieving the same within an object:

```
var a = Marionette.Object.extend({
    b: (function(){
        this.listenTo(this, "somethingElse", function(){...});
    })()
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/962040/1225328

Comment: What do you mean? At the beginning of the `initialize` function, add `var self = this;`. Then, in the nested functions, use `self` everywhere you used `this`: `self.listenTo(self, "somethingElse", function(){...});`.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same result within an object? If I take the same code as above, but put the self invoking function into a property, than how could I provide `this` inside?

Comment: Could you provide this code in your question?

Comment: This is a weird usecase, since `b` will be `undefined`... Anyway, have you actually tried with `this` in this case? Because I believe that it should work as is...

Comment: Yes, I tried. It says the same (Cannot read property 'listenTo' of undefined).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `var self = this` idiom:

```js
var a = Marionette.Object.extend({
  initialize: function () {

    var self = this; // maintain a reference to initialize's this

    (function(){
        self.listenTo(self, "somethingElse", function(){...});
    })();

  }
});
```

More details: [What underlies this JavaScript idiom: var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/962033/1225328)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` to your function with `.bind(this)`:

```
var a = Marionette.Object.extend({
    b: (function(){
        this.listenTo(this, "somethingElse", function(){...});
    }.bind(this)()
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind