# use a parameter in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, sockets

actually i'm trying to call a function which is created in another "class", and i want to use is in the `socket.on (...)` but it is not working , it keeps showing

> this.function is not a function.

here is the code :

```
//calling the function 
    Serveur.prototype.traitementSurConnection = function(socket) {
var that = this
    socket.on('connection', function (creator, typeArtifact,idConteneur, typeConteneur) {

        that.addArtifact('momo', 'img', 1,0);

    })
};
```

//the function

```
ZoneCollaborative.prototype.addArtifact = function(creator, typeArtifact,idConteneur, typeConteneur) {

    // calcul d'un nouvel identifiant

    var id = this.setIdAr();

    console.log('    *** ZC : calcul nouveau IdArtifact = '+id);


    // création de l'artifact

    var monArtifact = new Artifact(id, creator, typeArtifact, idConteneur,

            typeConteneur);

    console.log('    *** ZC : creation artifact'+monArtifact.getId() );

    // ajout à la liste

    this.artifacts.push(monArtifact);


    console.log('    *** ZC : total artifact ='+ this.artifacts.length);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the context of `socket.on()`, `this` refers not to the function/object containing the `socket.on()` call, but rather the `socket` which is calling the `on` function.  This is typically how people would handle this problem:

```
var self = this;
socket.on('connection', function (creator, typeArtifact,idConteneur, typeConteneur) {

    self.addArtifact('momo', 'img', 1,0);

})
```

This is a common issue in JavaScript code, the `this` keyword is very dependent on the scope in which it's being used and so you often see this pattern being used to preserve a `this` into a new scope.

Here is a related SO post that has some additional information on this: [What underlies this JavaScript idiom: var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this)