# passing clicked event 'this' to another function, is this correct practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently trying to maintain an object approach, at the moment I want to call a toggle method when a click handler is actioned. So the handler is within the init method and when i click the link I call the toggle_pane() passing the link that's been click 'this', does this sound right or what should I be doing? All advice welcome!

Here is the snippet of code I'm working on:

JS

```
init: function(){

            var _ = this,
                slides_li = _.els.slides.children();

            // Click handlers
            slides_li.on('click', function(e) {
               _.toggle_pane(this); 
            });



        },
        toggle_pane: function(li){

            var _ = this,
                slides_li = _.els.slides.children();

            if( !$(li).hasClass('active')) {
             console.log( 'dont have active' );   
            }


        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/js-var-self-this

Comment: "this" shouldn't be passed as an argument, bind it to the function instead - _.toggle_pane.bind(this). 

Also as kevin said, the _ variable isn't the best naming convention

Comment: hi, sorry what do you mean by binding to the function instead?

Comment: something like this: slides_li.bind('click', _.toggle_pane.bind(this));

Comment: passing "this" as an argument is bad practice. you should be binding it like "_.toggle_pane.bind(this)" so that the "this" inside your toggle function has the correct scope

Comment: thanks @michael, so is this correct slides_li.bind('click', _this.toggle_pane.bind(this));

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a way to do it.  Although, a plain old underscore isn't the best variable name.  I'd recommend something a little clearer, like `var _this = this;`.

Try looking around the jQuery source code itself, which does some juggling with `this` quite a bit.

Comment: with jQuery it is becoming very common to use: var $this = $(this)