# Difference between self and this in javascript and when to use either of them

Tags: javascript, titanium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What underlies this JavaScript idiom: var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this)

I am confused that when to use self and this in javascript.
I know that *this* refers to current context and *self* refers to current window.
As I am developing an application in Titanium. I want to know when to use *self* or *this*
OR does is there is any concept of *self* in titanium development.

here is the sample code that i am doing in my titanium commonJS module

```
var auth = require('/SDKTest/auth');
var nodeAPI = require('/SDKTest/nodeAPI');
function myAPI() {
     this.auth = auth;
     this.nodeAPI = nodeAPI;
     return this;
    }
module.exports = myAPI;
```

This code works, but can I use *self* in place of *this* ? 
And instead of using *this* i can create a namespace and do something like this:

```
  function myAPI() {
     var api = {};
     api.auth = auth;
     api.nodeAPI = nodeAPI;
     return api;
    }
```

both the approaches work but what is the use of using *this* over here

Comment: Refer
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/js-var-self-this

Comment: i have updated my question added a sample code over there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confusing, it's like asking: Do I buy apples or tomatoes? The answer is, it really depends on what you want to do, since they're completely different.

Essentially, you have answered your own question to some extent, because you already know the differences between the two:

- `this` refers to the current context
- `self` refers to `window`

```
function myAPI() {
     this.auth = auth;
     this.nodeAPI = nodeAPI;
     return this;
    }
module.exports = myAPI;
```

You're asking whether you can use `self` instead. Think about it, what does `this` allow you to do? It allows you, to refer to the context. What is the context, well, it's `module` when you call `module.exports()`. And `module` is most likely not going to be `window`, so no, you can't use `self` here.

Does that answer the question?

The second code example seems to do something completely different. I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: @phantOm In second code i am just creating my own custom namespace which holds the auth and nodeAPI objects

Comment: @AjeetPratapMaurya yes, I see that. The thing is, that it's completely different. If you were to assign that one to `module.exports`, it would return `module.exports()` a *new* object with attributes `auth` and `nodeAPI`, rather than modifying `module` itself, as the first code does.

Answer (score 9):

`self` is not a JavaScript keyword! Programmers use that when defining classes to have always valid reference to object itself.

```
var Person = function() {
    var self = this;
    // private function
    function say(what) {
        alert(what);
    }
    self.fetchSomething = function() {
        var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload: function() {
                // in this case 'this' is referencing to xhr!!!
                say(this.responseText);
            }
        });
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.whatever.com');
        xhr.send();
    }
    return self;
}
var p = new Person();
p.fetchSomething();
```