# KnockoutJS: this / self objects output the entire Window object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I may be misunderstanding something here, but why do my `this` / `self` always output the entire Window object into the console?

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('My viewModel');
    console.log(self);
}();
```

This results in following console output

[image]

Am I completely misunderstsanding `this` object?

Comment: Possibly Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210978/difference-between-using-variable-self-vs-this

Comment: Usually self is the last instantiated object in this case, you are setting it to `this`, so logging `self` will log the contents of `this`

Comment: I just realized that i've been using `var blah = function() {}`, instead of `function blah() {}`. Second one gives me the expected result! Argh.

Comment: No, the problem is that you have the `()` in the last line. It calls the function **immediately** and assigns the return value (`undefined`) to `myViewModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I completely misunderstsanding this object?

Could be, but I don't know what you expect, so I can't answer that.

The reason why `this` refers to `window` is that the function is executed immediately. In a function executed as `foo()` (non-strict mode), `this` refers to the global object (`window`).

Note the `()` at the end:

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('My viewModel');
    console.log(self);
}(); // <--
```

This makes the function execute immediately and return `undefined` to `myViewModel`, which you can easily verify by adding a `console.log` statement inside and after the function.

I guess you want to omit those and assign the function itself to `myViewModel`:

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log('My viewModel');
    console.log(self);
}; // <--
```

[Learn more about `this`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)