# Countdown Timer Objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, counter

I would like to create a simple timer in Javascript that counts down from a given time until it hits 0. I found this [tutorial](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51639-how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-in-javascript/#axzz2GwCO9y00) which worked perfectly. My problem is that I need to place multiple timers on the same page. This tutorial obviously won't do that because it uses global variables (I'm new to JS/Programming so I might not be using the right terms). I tried to re-create the same thing only creating each timer as it's own Object so that they don't interfere with eachother. This is what I have.

```
function taskTimer(name, startTime) {
  this.timer = name;
  this.totalSeconds = startTime;
  this.tick = function() {
    if (this.totalSeconds <= 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.totalSeconds -= 1;
    this.updateTimer();
    // window.setTimeout("this.tick()", 1000);
  };
  this.updateTimer = function(){
    this.seconds = this.totalSeconds;

    this.hours = Math.floor(this.seconds / 3600);
    this.seconds -= this.hours * (3600);

    this.minutes = Math.floor(this.seconds / 60);
    this.seconds -= this.minutes * (60);

    this.timeString = this.leadingZero(this.hours) + ":" + this.leadingZero(this.minutes) + ":" + this.leadingZero(this.seconds);
    return this.timeString;
  };
  this.leadingZero = function(time){
    return (time < 10) ? "0" + time : + time;
  };
}
var testTimer = new taskTimer("timer", 30);
testTimer.tick();
```

I created one at the end there. Running 
`testTimer.updateTimer();` returns `00:00:30` which is correct, but running `testTimer.tick();` returns no value. There is obviously something wrong with that part of the code I just can't figure it out.

Comment: how can you tell if this is working or not? you're not painting any of the timer values anywhere.

Comment: because the updateTimer method works, so calling the tick method should return the same value because it calls the updateTimer method inside of it.

Comment: "`testTimer.tick();` returns no value" Is that the problem you are trying to solve? If so, that function doesn't return anything, ever. You need a `return` statement in there.

Comment: But testTimer.tick(); calls the updateTimer(); method which does return a value. Shouldn't that mean testTimer.tick(); would return that same value?

Comment: @SMDeConto updateTimer returns a value to tick, but tick doesn't return it to you.

Comment: @SMDeConto `this.updateTimer();` at the end of `this.tick` should be `return this.updateTimer();`

Comment: @SMDeConto I think is late but I was posted my version anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a few problems.

1. You're calling `updateTimer()` inside of your `tick` method, so it
   won't ever reach outside of there unless you return it.
2. With your current setup, you'd have to call `tick` manually every time you wanted to update the clock, and if you don't do that precisely every one second the timer will be inaccurate.
3. To go with #2, you shouldn't decrement `totalSeconds` like you are because it isn't guaranteed that it will be exactly one second between triggers of your timeout. Use dates instead.

Here's what I would do: http://jsfiddle.net/R4hnE/3/

```
// I added optional callbacks. This could be setup better, but the details of that are negligible. 
function TaskTimer(name, durationInSeconds, onEnd, onTick) {
    var endTime,
        self = this, // store a reference to this since the context of window.setTimeout is always window
        running = false;
    this.name = name;
    this.totalSeconds = durationInSeconds;

    var go = (function tick() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        if (now >= endTime) {
            if (typeof onEnd === "function") onEnd.call(self);
            return;
        }
        self.totalSeconds = Math.round((endTime - now) / 1000); // update totalSeconds placeholder
        if (typeof onTick === "function") onTick.call(self);
        window.setTimeout(tick, 1000 / 12); // you can increase the denominator for greater accuracy. 
    });

    // this is an instance method to start the timer
    this.start = function() {
        if (running) return; // prevent multiple calls to start

        running = true;
        endTime = new Date().getTime() + durationInSeconds * 1000; // this is when the timer should be done (with current functionality. If you want the ability to pause the timer, the logic would need to be updated)
        go();
    };
}
// no reason to make this an instance method :)
TaskTimer.prototype.toTimeString = function() {
    var hrs = Math.floor(this.totalSeconds / 60 / 60),
        min = Math.floor(this.totalSeconds / 60 - hrs * 60),
        sec = this.totalSeconds % 60;

    return [hrs.padLeft("0", 2), min.padLeft("0", 2), sec.padLeft("0", 2)].join(" : ");
};

var task = new TaskTimer("task1", 30, function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = this.toTimeString();
    alert('done');
}, function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = this.toTimeString();
});
```

Comment: Also note that convention would have classes start with Uppercase letters.

Comment: Ill work on understand this lol. Also, I am trying to have multiple timers running at the same time.

Comment: Fantastic. I don't understand it all yet but I'll get it :) Thank you!

Comment: @SMDeConto do you have any specific questions?

Comment: I will I'm sure but so far I'm having fun figuring out some of the methods/syntaxes you've used. I just started school and am trying to do some independent studying on my own during break so I created this project for myself. I think it's helpful for me to read someone elses code. I'll let you know if there's anything I can't figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I always have problems with `this` and in one instance, within the function, I had to redefine it:

```
this.tick = function() {
  self=this;
  if (self.totalSeconds <= 0) {
    return;
  }
  self.totalSeconds -= 1;
  self.updateTimer();
   // window.setTimeout("self.tick()", 1000);
};
```

Here is another post about that: [var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/js-var-self-this)

Comment: actually you don't need this in code you provided. but when you use callback, like in setTimeout or something else - you do need it (seems you wanted to highlight this with commenting it)

Comment: Why quote the call to tick? I think this is a bit cleaner: setTimeout(self.tick, 1000);

Comment: You're declaring self as a global. tsk tsk.

Comment: I only commented it because I was testing the tick method and didn't want it to run again. This didn't work for me either, it just froze up.

Answer (score 0):

My version, you can see at: 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/hmariod/N7haK/4/

```
var tmArray = new Array();
var timerRef, timerId=0;


function newTimer(){
    try{
        if(tmArray.length > 4) throw "Too much timers";
        var countDown = parseInt(document.getElementById("tCountown").value,10);
        if(isNaN(countDown)) throw "tCountown is NaN";
        var tmName = document.getElementById("tName").value;
        var nt = new taskTimer(++timerId, tmName, countDown);
        createTmElement(timerId, tmName);
        tmArray.push(nt);
        if(!timerRef) timerRef = setInterval(timerFn, 1000);
        showTimers();
    }catch(er){
        alert("newTimer:" + er);
    }
}

function taskTimer(id, name, tCountown) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tName = name;
    this.tCountown = tCountown;
}


function timerFn(){
    try{
        var i;
        killTimer = true;
        for(i = 0; i < tmArray.length; i++){
           tmArray[i].tCountown--;
            if(tmArray[i].tCountown < 0){
                tmArray[i].tCountown = 0;
            }else{
                killTimer = false;
            }
        }
        if(killTimer) clearInterval(timerRef);
        showTimers();
    }catch(er){
        clearInterval(timerRef);
        aler("timerFn: " + er);
    }
}
```