# Is there any difference between this and self keyword usage in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i just wonder is there any difference between self and this keyword usage or both same

### see this example which use this keyword

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
  this.first = ko.observable(first);
  this.last = ko.observable(last);
  this.full = ko.computed(function() {
     return this.first() + " " + this.last();
  }, this);
};
```

### see this example which use self keyword instead of this keyword

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
  var self=this;
  self.first = ko.observable(first);
  self.last = ko.observable(last);
  self.full = ko.computed(function() {
     return self.first() + " " + self.last();
  }, self);
};
```

which approach is good and why accepted ? thanks

Comment: *this* is not the same as "this" when the code runs, that's why the initial "this" is backed up in "self" ;)

Comment: already answered, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163248/whats-the-advantage-of-using-var-self-this-in-knockout-js-view-models

Comment: *self* isn't a [*keyword*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.1). If it was, it couldn't be used as an identifier.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/tyBOndQfmxg

Answer (score 1):

[Reading the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) it seems that `ko.computed` essentially returns a bound function using the second arg as the context.

So, no, it does not seem to make any *practical* difference in this case.

There is a subtle difference inside the bound function:

```
self.full = ko.computed(function() {
     return self.first() + " " + self.last();
  }, self);
```

The `self` inside the function (`self.first()`) is creating a closure to the outer scope (where self is declared).  So, the second argument defining context is then not really needed:

```
self.full = ko.computed(function() {
     return self.first() + " " + self.last();
  });
```

However, this could be changed to this without changing behaviour:

```
self.full = ko.computed(function() {
     return this.first() + " " + this.last();
  }, self);
```

Comment: u give two example code but i just do not understand what u try to say? both code look ok but not sure does 2 routine work in same way?

Comment: @Mou Your question is really around how binding context works in JavaScript (in general).

Comment: i like to know what u r trying to say by giving 3 sample code?

Comment: i just really do not understand what u try to say giving 3 sample code. can explain it more easy way like what u r trying to say.

Comment: Best to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: and this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures