# Knockout not providing Updated value using value binding

Tags: knockout.js, console.log

I want to print the value of an input element in console using knockout.

When I try to print that value I am getting "result" instead of the value of the textbox.

```js
var ViewModel = {
   name: ko.observable("name"),
   company: ko.observable("company"),
   submit: ko.observable("Submit"),
   onsubmit: function(){
      console.log(name);
   }
}

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<form>
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" data-bind="value:name"/>
   <label>Company</label>
   <input type="text" data-bind="value:company"/>
   <button data-bind="click:onsubmit,text:submit"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way. I like to declare a function for my viewmodel so that later it can be used to initialize another new object.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable("name");
  self.company = ko.observable("company");
  self.submit = ko.observable("Submit");
  self.onsubmit = function(){
   alert(self.name())
   console.log(self.name());
  };
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name"/>
<label>Company</label>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: company"/>
<button data-bind="click: onsubmit, text: submit"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you please explain me what I was doing wrong

Comment: I believe the problem is because when you call console.log(name), name there doesn't refer to the same name observable value that you've declared. And this can be fixed by doing var self = this; and you use self.name to make sure it refers to the right name object

Comment: can we directly use "this.name " instead?

Comment: and also you have changed name into  function(). What significance does that hold?

Comment: That's how you read a value of an observable object. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: Thanks. Great Help

Comment: @M.Ihsan In fact it would have been enough change `console.log(name);` to `console.log(this.name())`. In knockout event handlers, `this` will be a reference to the viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yup, that's correct. I was a bit mixed up before. I just like to do `var self = this` so that I don't even need to think about this scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163248/whats-the-advantage-of-using-var-self-this-in-knockout-js-view-models.