# Backbone View - How can I pass 'this' through multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

This is from my Backbone View.  But I keep getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined`.

How can I keep this so that I can add a new model to my collection?

```
addGroupModal: function() {
  $('#add-group-modal').modal('show');
  // Manual Event Listener for Submit Button
  $("#add-group-submit-button").click(function(){

      var newGroup = new KAC.Models.KeepAContactGroup({ name: '123', list_order: '2' });
      console.log(newGroup)
      newGroup.save();
      this.collection.add(newGroup)

  });
},
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this (and probably several other questions on SO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scope of your anonymous function (callback) `this` represents not your view but the prototype (class) created by that function.

So that you should force that function to use particular `this` context.

You can use either Underscore/LoDash [`_.bind()`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) method
or native [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (for all major browsers and IE > 8).

```
addGroupModal: function() {
  $('#add-group-modal').modal('show');
  // Manual Event Listener for Submit Button
  $("#add-group-submit-button").click(_.bind(function() {

      var newGroup = new KAC.Models.KeepAContactGroup({
          name: '123',
          list_order: '2'
      });
      console.log(newGroup);
      newGroup.save();
      this.collection.add(newGroup);

  }, this));
}
```

Native bind:

```
$("#add-group-submit-button").click(function() {
    // ...
}.bind(this));
```