# What is "this" in ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

I cannot understand "this" in AngularJS.
I found it on function which was associated with ng-click.

html

```
<button ng-click="func()"></button>
```

javascript:

```
function func(){
    console.log(this);
}
```

I want to use "this" through another function. So I want to know how to access "this" on another function. Please teach me.

Comment: this is not specific to angularjs it's vanilla javascript.
Maybe relevant : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you can easily find out for yourself what this is. The question lacks presentation of a minimal understanding of what `this` means in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the comments saying that you could have found that by yourself but we all started from scratch one day... so:

To use `this` in another function:

```
function func(){
  anotherFunc(this);
}

function anotherFunc(oldThis){
// do something...
}
```

You should also read about the famous: `var self = this;`

[var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this)

[What underlies this JavaScript idiom: var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this)

Comment: I'm sorry for leaving without saying I solved this problem by myself. I'm able to do thing I want to do. Thank you for answering.