# Passing element through to a function: 'this' getting lost somewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript function, which acts like a keyup but waits for the user to stop typing:

```
function afterDelayedKeyup(elements, action, delay){
  if(typeof(elements) == "string"){
    elements = $(elements);
  }
  elements.keyup(function(){
    if(typeof(window['inputTimeout']) != "undefined"){
      clearTimeout(inputTimeout);
    }  
    inputTimeout = setTimeout(action, delay);
  });
}
```

I call it like this:

```
afterDelayedKeyup(".foo", function(){ doSomething();}, 1000);
```

It works:  if you start typing in a .foo input, then when you've not typed anything for 1 second, doSomething() is called.

What i want to do next, is to pass through the element it was called on into the doSomething() function, so doSomething knows which element triggered it to be called.  I've tried this:

```
afterDelayedKeyup(".foo", function(){ doSomething(this);}, 1000);
```

and

```
afterDelayedKeyup(".foo", function(){ doSomething($(this));}, 1000);
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  If my doSomething() function looks like this for example:

```
function doSomething(element){
  console.log("element.attr('class') = "+element.attr('class'));
  console.log("$(element).attr('class') = "+$(element).attr('class'));
}
```

Neither of them will log out 'foo' like i'd expect. I get either `TypeError: undefined is not a function` (for the first log line) or `$(element).attr('class') = undefined` for the second log line.

I think that the value of 'this' is getting lost somewhere in between being passed through to afterDelayedKeyup() and being passed through to setTimeout() but i can't work out what's happened.

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: Don't think its a dupe

Comment: My question is not "what does 'this' mean in javascript?" so that's not a duplicate.  My question is "My code doesn't work, i think it's got something to do with 'this' but i'm not sure, can anyone see the specific problem?".  Thanks though :)

Comment: Well, maybe your question comes from the misunderstanding of how `this` works?

Comment: My question also comes from an incomplete understanding of Javascript in general, but directing me to the Javascript page on wikipedia wouldn't be a valuable comment.

Comment: I'm pointing you to other SO answers. In any case, check this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this.

Comment: The misunderstanding comes from the OP's misunderstanding of setTimeout. The callback in setTimeout does not accept a parameter, so we adjust for that and pass through $(this). See my answer.

Comment: @monarch he is not trying to pass in a paramater, `delay` is the time

Comment: @Andrei I'm actually talking about `action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event object [should tell you which input element you're typing in](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```
afterDelayedKeyup(".foo", function(e){ doSomething(e);}, 1000);
```

Just send it to your action:

```
elements.keyup(function(e){
  if(typeof(window['inputTimeout']) != "undefined"){
    clearTimeout(inputTimeout);
  }  
  inputTimeout = setTimeout(action(e.target), delay);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You call your function like this :

```
setTimeout(action, delay);
```

Which mean when you do that :

```
function(){ doSomething(this);}
```

`this` will be the window object.

Try using `.bind` like this :

```
setTimeout(action.bind(this), delay);
```

`.bind()` will change the value `this` inside the `action` function for the first arguments.

Here's the doc for `.bind` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

---

As Andrei Nemes said :

> Also, it is not really necessary to wrap `doSomething()` in an anonymous function, you can get away with just passing the reference `afterDelayedKeyup(".foo", doSomething, 1000);`

Comment: Also, it is not really necessary to wrap `doSomething()` in an anonymous function, you can get away with just passing the reference `afterDelayedKeyup(".foo", doSomething, 1000);`

Comment: @AndreiNemes Totally true, may i had that to the answer?

Comment: Yeah sure, go ahead! Also, note that `Function.prototype.bind` is not supported in Internet Explorer 8, so if you want to get around that you can use jQuery's proxy: `setTimeout($.proxy(action, this), delay);`

Answer (score 1):

Before `afterDelayedKeyup`, set `var t=$(this);` and then use `t` in the callback function instead.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that happens because of closure. The new function within the afterDelayedKeyup creates a new local context or scope so "this" will refer to the Window object since it is global. To solve this I believe you need to do something like this:

afterDelayedKeyup.call("object you want to pass to the function",[array of the arguments]);

so I guess it should be afterDelayedKeyup.call(this,".foo",1000) and your afterDelayedKeyup should then invoke the anonymous function

```
function afterDelayedKeyup(className, duration)
{
  function(){
    doSomething(this);
}(); //not sure if you want it to be immediately invoked
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`doSomething` doesn't get executed until it's fired off by the timer, at which point the `this` reference no longer exists (and even if it did, wouldn't point to the object you'd be expecting). Save `this` explicitly to another variable, then reference that variable in the function you pass.

`var tempThis = this;
afterDelayedKeyup(".foo", function(){ doSomething($(tempThis));}, 1000);`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me - i  get the same ` undefined is not a function` error.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout's callback function does not accept a parameter in the OP's current structure. A new parameter is needed  like so: `inputTimeout = setTimeout(action, delay, $(this));`

```
function afterDelayedKeyup(elements, action, delay){
  if(typeof(elements) == "string"){
    elements = $(elements);
  }
  elements.keyup(function(){
    if(typeof(window['inputTimeout']) != "undefined"){
      clearTimeout(inputTimeout);
    }  
    inputTimeout = setTimeout(action, delay, $(this));
  });
}
```

Then you can call

```
afterDelayedKeyup(".foo", doSomething, 1000);
```

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong, it does accept parameters. Just not in IE9 and lower.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't in the form that OP had it.. you can't do `setTimeout(doSomething(this), 1000);`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon try the following code in console: `setTimeout(alert("HI"), 10000)` and you'll see what i mean

Comment: I know what you mean since `()` will call the function. But you can pass parameter. Try this : `setTimeout(alert, 2000, 'hi');`

Answer (score 1):

Your code follows some pretty weird pattern. Basically what you want to achieve is a basic debounce:

```
var keyUpHandler = function( originalEvent ) {
    var invoker = $( originalEvent.target ); //Your "this"
    console.log( invoker );
    // do whatever you need
};

var keyUpDebouncer = function( event ) {
    if ( keyUpDebouncer.timeout ) {
        clearTimout( keyUpDebouncer.timeout );
    }
    keyUpDebouncer.timeout = setTimeout( function() {
        keyUpHandler( event );
    }, 1000 );
};

$( '.my-keyboard-receiver' ).on( 'keyup', keyUpDebouncer );
```