# Retrieve values from dynamically created textbox on knockout + MVVM

Tags: jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I am new to this knockout js and MVVM architecture. Am not able to retrieve dynamically created textbox values on button click event.

**Code:HTML**

```
   <div data-bind="foreach: cources">
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: textValue"/>
      <br>          
   </div>

 <input type="button" data-bind="click:retrieve" value="Value"/>
```

**Code:js**

```
function CourseViewModel(){
      textValue = ko.observable(''); 
}

var ViewModel= {
      cources : ko.observableArray([new CourseViewModel()]),
      retrieve: function()
      {
          var abc = $.parseJSON(ko.toJSON({ textValue: ViewModel.cources})); 
          alert(abc.textValue());
      }
}

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function(index):35 ViewModel.retrieveknockout-min.js:59 (anonymous function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few different problems:

- You need to check out how constructor functions work. The [KO docs have some info](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this) on related subjects, as does [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/337878/419956). If you want to reference `ViewModel` from inside a function called on such a `ViewModel` you could use for example the below pattern.
- You expect `abc` to have a *function* called `textValue`, but that's after you have gone to-and-from JSON. JSON will not preserve functions like that.
- Your course view model does not expose `textValue` externally. You need to export it, e.g. using the `self` idiom. See example below.
- You have to change `cources` to `cources()`: it's an observableArray and to retrieve it's value you need to *execute* the observable.

```js
var CourseViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.textValue = ko.observable('initial value');
};

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.cources = ko.observableArray([new CourseViewModel()]);
    self.retrieve = function() {
        var abc = ko.toJSON({ textValue: self.cources() }); 
        alert(abc);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: cources">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: textValue"/>
</div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click:retrieve" value="Value"/>
```

If you insist on staying away from constructor functions for ViewModel you could still do it, but you have to *amend* `ViewModel` with `retrieve` after you've instantiated with all properties you wish to use. Like this:

```js
var CourseViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.textValue = ko.observable('initial value');
};

var viewModel = {
    cources: ko.observableArray([new CourseViewModel()])
};

viewModel.retrieve = function() {
    var abc = ko.toJSON({ textValue: viewModel.cources() }); 
    alert(abc);
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: cources">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: textValue"/>
</div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click:retrieve" value="Value"/>
```

You should really go through [the Knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/). It shouldn't take very long, and will quickly save you a *lot* of time struggling with this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks for quick response but I still have problem, Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

In your code everything is fine instead of your bindings with the current object.You need to bind your data and functions with `this` like,

```js
function CourseViewModel() {
    this.textValue = ko.observable('');
}
var ViewModel = function(){
    this.cources= ko.observableArray([new CourseViewModel()]);
    this.retrieve= function () {
        var abc = ko.toJSON({
            textValue: this.cources
        });
        alert(abc);
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: cources">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: textValue" />
    <br/>
</div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click:retrieve" value="Value" />
```

Comment: I got my mistake and that is, "this" keyword missed, thanks for spending time with this post

Comment: I have another clarification, For loading single textbox dynamically "foreach"(data-bind) is correct or not. "<div data-bind="foreach: cources"></div>

Comment: no, if the textbox is single then avoid using `foreach`.