# How to update original this when cloning with extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm trying to clone some objects using the jquery extend method.  However, after cloning my object, I realized that some methods of the cloned object were modifying values from the original object so I thought both objects properties may be pointing at the same variable.

After running some tests, I figured that the properties of my cloned object got copied correctly... including the local `self` variable (which is used to hold the reference to the original `this` of the class instance).  Since the cloned `self` is still pointing at the original instance, the methods referring to that variable are targeting the properties of the original instance instead of it's own instance:

```
var Animal = function() {

  var self = this;

  this.sound = "";

  this.talk = function(){
    alert(self.sound);
  };

};

var dog = new Animal();
dog.sound = "Woof";
dog.talk(); //Woof as expected

var cat = $.extend(true, {}, dog); 
cat.sound = "Meow";
cat.talk(); //Woof... but Meow was expected
```

The extend method behavior does make sense... but is there a **generic** way to make sure the `self` variable refers to the new cloned object?  By generic, I mean that the `self` variable may have a different name (that, _this, etc) and that I would like to avoid adding custom methods to every class just to update the `self` variable.

You should also keep in mind that the `self` variable is private (and there's many good reasons to keep it like this) so this mean you can't set it outside the instance.

Comment: `extend` extends the object, it doesn't create a new instance. I think the only (and right) way to do this, is to create a new Animal, instead of copying the old animal.

Comment: Or, create a method that changes the property with the correct context -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1572gy9o/**

Comment: Indeed... It makes more sense to take an animal as prototype and create new instances from there. You can make sublevels as you like. Might seem a bit weird to convert a dog into a cat by extending it.

Comment: @adeneo `extend` is still the reference method when we talk about cloning object even if it's not it main purpose.  Creating a new instance would be an easy solution to implement (in my case) but there's always a voice in my head saying "Find a generic solution you lazy programmer!".

Comment: But the generic and correct solution to create a new Animal **is** to create a new instance of the `Animal` class, not clone the dog, so to speak. `$.extend` is not the reference when it comes to instances of classes, that's something it's generally not used for.

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of fact, you don't need the `var self = this` construct for this use case.

Just made a small test here: http://jsfiddle.net/quwdeafd/
Take a look at the scope of `this`. 
Isn't that what you were looking for?

```
var Animal = function() {

  this.sound = "";
  this.talk = function(){
      console.log(this); //Logs Animal the first time, object the second 
      console.log(this.sound); //Logs Woof and meow 
  };

};

var dog = new Animal();
dog.sound = "Woof";
dog.talk(); 

var cat = $.extend(true, {}, dog); 
cat.sound = "Meow";
cat.talk();
```

Small remark: usually it's custom to put this method on the prototype of the object:

```
Animal.prototype.talk = function(){
      console.log(this); 
      console.log(this.sound);
  };
```

Because it makes the method immediately available without needing to be initialized on every instantiation.

Comment: `var self = this` is actually a fairly good practice, since `this` changes depending on scope, so if you need to access `this` in deeper scopes, where `this` changes, assigning it to `self`, or any variable will allow it to be accessed in deeper scopes.

[Check out this StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this)

Comment: It works fine without the `self` variable, but I think the point was to actually keep it, as the OP seems to need it for something?

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi I agree, I use _.bind instead, relatively often. But for this example, it doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: @adeneo Possibly, I don't know. But if not, then the solution is pretty simple :-)

Comment: I guess you already figured out my Animal was just an example.  As Brandon Anzaldi pointed out, my real class has many scope level and the `self` is really handy (see mandatory) when you enter those scopes.

Answer (score 1):

As adeneo pointed out, the problem is at another level.  Even if the `extend` is often referred to as a cloning method, it's wasn't made for this purpose.  The problem mentioned in this question is a good example of it's limitations.

For the record, I stopped using the `extend` method for cloning purpose and I solved my problem by replacing it with a cloning method taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/315493).