# not able to bind web api result to observable array + Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

observable array not reflecting data on binding the output of webapi. where as it reflects data on binding hard-coded array. what is wrong in the code function GetAllCustomers.

```
function CustomerDataModel() {

    this.customerList = ko.observableArray([
    { FirstName: "John" },
        { FirstName: "Sam" },
        { FirstName: "Peter" },
        { FirstName: "Vicky"},
        { FirstName: "Amar" }
    ]);        


    this.GetAllCustomers = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/komvc/api/customer',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {

                var mappedCusts = $.map(data, function (item) { return { FirstName: item.FirstName }; });
                console.log(mappedCusts[0].FirstName);
                this.customerList = ko.observableArray(this.mappedCusts);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(this.customerList)));
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });        
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new CustomerDataModel());
```

//html

```
<div>

    <div data-bind="foreach: customerList">
        <br />
        <span data-bind='text: FirstName' />
    </div>

    <button id="btnGet" data-bind="click:GetAllCustomers">Get All Customers</button>
</div>
```

//my web api is returning

```
{"Id":1,"FirstName":"Rakesh","LastName":"Suresh","Phone":"919239123","Address":"Bangalore"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the call:

```
this.customerList = ko.observableArray(this.mappedCusts);
```

You are overriding your `customerList` with a completely new observable array which breaks the KO bindings.

What you need to do is to update the already existing `customerList` with:

```
this.customerList(mappedCusts);
```

You also need to fix your `this` handling because inside the `success` handler `this` definitely won't be your viewmodel object...

So you need to use the `context: this,` option on your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   //...
   context: this,
   success: function (data) {
    //this now refers to the same object as this in GetAllCustomers 
   }
});
```

Or you can store a reference to the correct `this` as described: [var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this?rq=1) or use the [`bind` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), etc.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsb1bfLt/).

By the way your API is responding with a single object and not an array. Make sure that you calling the correct URL which returns an array, something like:

```
[{"Id":1,"FirstName":"Rakesh","LastName":"Suresh","Phone":"919239123","Address":"Bangalore"}]
```