# How can I refer the 'real' this in an attached event handler using JavaScript OOP?

Tags: javascript, oop

How can I refer the 'real' this in an attached event handler using JavaScript OOP?

Is is the best practice to refer to the instance by using the local variable 'anyVariable'?

```
var myClass = (function () {
function myClass(gridId) {
    $(function () {
        // misc init code replaced here
        this.initKeyboard();
    });

}

myClass.prototype.initKeyboard = function () {
    var anyVariable = this; // keyword 'this' is clearly referring here to the instance
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        // I would like to refer here to the instance.
        // However it seems that the keyword 'this' refers here to the function (?)
        // Is is the best practice here to refer to the instance by using the local variable 'anyVariable'?
        anyVariable.myMember(...); //???
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Also, you can use $.proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual variable name is `self`, `that`, or `_this` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337878/var-self-this) for more details), but yes, that's the usual way to keep the needed `this` value when the context changes